# How do I check if an object has a specific property in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

How do I check if an object has a specific property in JavaScript?

Consider:

```
x = {'key': 1};
if ( x.hasOwnProperty('key') ) {
    //Do this
}
```

Is that the best way to do it?

Comment: I wrote a jsperf test with everyone's answers to see which is fastest: http://jsperf.com/dictionary-contains-key

Comment: ('propertyName' in Object) ? 'property is there' : 'property is not there'

Comment: @styfle thanks for the jsperf test. `in` and `hasOwnProperty` came out *way* slower than the others for me (98% slower). I'm not surprised about `hasOwnProperty` being slower but I am surprised about `in`.

Comment: There’s a new stage 3 proposal, [`Object.hasOwn`](//github.com/tc39/proposal-accessible-object-hasownproperty), which addresses a few of the problems of `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty`.

Answer (score 1727, accepted):

### 2022 UPDATE

### [`Object.hasOwn()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwn)

> `Object.hasOwn()` is recommended over `Object.hasOwnProperty()` because it works for objects created using `Object.create(null)` and with objects that have overridden the inherited `hasOwnProperty()` method. While it is possible to workaround these problems by calling `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty()` on an external object, `Object.hasOwn()` is more intuitive.

##### Example

```js
const object1 = {
  prop: 'exists'
};

console.log(Object.hasOwn(object1, 'prop'));
// expected output: true
```

---

### Original answer

I'm really confused by the answers that have been given - most of them are just outright incorrect. Of course you can have object properties that have undefined, null, or false values. So simply reducing the property check to `typeof this[property]` or, even worse, `x.key` will give you completely misleading results.

It depends on what you're looking for. If you want to know if an object physically contains a property (and it is not coming from somewhere up on the prototype chain) then `object.hasOwnProperty` is the way to go. All modern browsers support it. (It was missing in older versions of Safari - 2.0.1 and older - but those versions of the browser are rarely used any more.)

If what you're looking for is if an object has a property on it that is iterable (when you iterate over the properties of the object, it will appear) then doing: `prop in object` will give you your desired effect.

Since using `hasOwnProperty` is probably what you want, and considering that you may want a fallback method, I present to you the following solution:

```
var obj = {
    a: undefined,
    b: null,
    c: false
};

// a, b, c all found
for ( var prop in obj ) {
    document.writeln( "Object1: " + prop );
}

function Class(){
    this.a = undefined;
    this.b = null;
    this.c = false;
}

Class.prototype = {
    a: undefined,
    b: true,
    c: true,
    d: true,
    e: true
};

var obj2 = new Class();

// a, b, c, d, e found
for ( var prop in obj2 ) {
    document.writeln( "Object2: " + prop );
}

function hasOwnProperty(obj, prop) {
    var proto = obj.__proto__ || obj.constructor.prototype;
    return (prop in obj) &&
        (!(prop in proto) || proto[prop] !== obj[prop]);
}

if ( Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty ) {
    var hasOwnProperty = function(obj, prop) {
        return obj.hasOwnProperty(prop);
    }
}

// a, b, c found in modern browsers
// b, c found in Safari 2.0.1 and older
for ( var prop in obj2 ) {
    if ( hasOwnProperty(obj2, prop) ) {
        document.writeln( "Object2 w/ hasOwn: " + prop );
    }
}
```

The above is a working, cross-browser, solution to `hasOwnProperty()`, with one caveat: It is unable to distinguish between cases where an identical property is on the prototype and on the instance - it just assumes that it's coming from the prototype. You could shift it to be more lenient or strict, based upon your situation, but at the very least this should be more helpful.

Comment: @grantwparks If you are building a simple slider plugin and want to check for the existence of an options item, then this might be more than needed indeed. You can just do something like `var w = opts.w || 100;`. But if you are onto a library kind of something, you may need to go a little bit farther at some parts.

Comment: @kralco626: Yes, nowadays I feel it's pretty safe to go with hasOwnProperty() – but for truly safe cross-browser solution, go with John's.

Comment: What about _temporary_ changing `__proto__` to null? Simple impl: `function hasOwnProperty(obj, prop) {
 var temp = obj.__proto__;
 obj.__proto__ = null;
 var ret = prop in obj;
 obj.__proto__ = temp;
 return ret;
}` (Case with `obj.constructor.prototype` should be added).

Comment: @Kasztan `__proto__` is non-standard and doesn't work in some older browsers. And even with the recent addition of `Object.getPrototypeOf` the standard says you still can't change the prototype of an existing object.

Comment: John Resig's answers does not seem to work in IE8, see it fail in this live demo http://jsbin.com/tovaburefeva/1/edit?js,output . I think it's because `hasOwnProperty() "is not supported on host objects for Internet Explorer 8 and below"` see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/328kyd6z(v=vs.94).aspx and also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8157700/object-has-no-hasownproperty-method-i-e-its-undefined-ie8

Comment: A `for(prop in object)` loop iterates only enumerable properties. However, `prop in object` checks whether `object` has the property `prop` somewhere in the prototypical chain, independently on whether it's enumerable or not.

Comment: As a side note to functions declared inside if's, this works in all modern browsers I'm aware of, but it is not supported by PhantomJS.

Comment: Since ECMA Script Version 6 embeds the Reflect function that is the preferred way to go. It has a 'has()' and a 'get()' which makes it very easy to create a wrapper to get Safe-Arguments. 
Not all browsers may support this functionality (not in IE and Opera), but hat will change soon. Use the ECMA 'use version 6' to ensure a correct Script version.

Comment: Word of warning: don't use `in` check on primitives.

Comment: why can't you just pass the property in through the subscript operator and check if it returns a falsy value? if you're looking for a property name that isn't shared in the prototype chain, then this is too much work

Comment: In 2022 you can use Object.hasOwn(). He doesn't seem to be active anymore, but anyone looking for JavaScript books, this guy has written the best imo. I think he uses Manning for a publisher, which is a company that I really like.

Comment: Note that `hasOwn` is not supported by Safari <15.4 which, as of 2022, still comprises a fair number of users (~10% of Safari users on our particular site). `core-js` will polyfill it, but `core-js-pure` *does not*.

Comment: Don't use `Object.hasOwn` unless you're writing server side code. It won't work on browsers that don't support it. Use `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call` instead. Or polyfill it first with something like `Object.hasOwn = Object.hasOwn || function(obj, prop) {return {}.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, prop)}`

Answer (score 325):

With [Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) or ([even better](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13789618/differences-between-lodash-and-underscore-js)) [Lodash](http://lodash.com/):

```
_.has(x, 'key');
```

Which calls `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty`, but (a) is shorter to type, and (b) uses "a safe reference to `hasOwnProperty`" (i.e. it works even if `hasOwnProperty` is overwritten).

In particular, Lodash defines `_.has` as:

```
function has(object, key) {
  return object ? hasOwnProperty.call(object, key) : false;
}
// hasOwnProperty = Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty
```

### 2023 Update

As noted in John Resig's answer, this is now essentially built-in with [`Object.hasOwn`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwn). Lodash/underscore remain fallbacks for cases where `Object.hasOwn` is [not available](https://caniuse.com/?search=object.hasown).

Comment: I would guess it's because "add this library" is seldom a popular solution even when the question is about complex DOM manipulation and the answer is "go use jQuery".

Comment: I see your point, @sudowned, thanks. Incidentally, if one were averse to including the entire lodash library one could compile subcomponents or `npm install lodash.has` which exposes an npm module with just a `has` function that compiles down to 175 bytes when minified. It is also insightful to look at the `lodash.has/index.js` to see how a very popular and trusted library works.

Comment: and `lodash`'s versions works with this:

`.has(undefined, 'someKey') => false` while `underscore` returns `undefined`

Comment: Thanks @BradParks -- I had not actually looked at the documentation for the `underscore` version, so I am sure this might be a useful point for someone reading this.

Comment: Thanks @brian-m-hunt I'm already including lodash, started searching around before I should have been RTFM.

Comment: I don't believe using a library is an acceptable answer because the question asks "in JavaScript" not "using a JavaScript library."

Comment: To everyone whining about adding `lodash` as "yet another" dependency: it's a fairly common (if not THE most common) library for this sort of thing. Have fun reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Even if you want to reinvent the wheel, checking out existing wheels is not a bad idea.

Comment: Also, the OP may not have even known about it. So saying 'in JavaScript' or 'with JQuery' doesn't mean they are not open to new libraries they may not have known existed and were just trying to use basic Javascript or Jquery because they thought that was all they had at their disposal for this. But, the selected answer mentioning using 'hasOwnProperty' is the simplest way to do this.

Comment: For the love of God use Lodash or whatever other library is available until JS sorts  out its pretty, petty little head. At least if you go that route you are off-loading the ridiculous amount of hoop-jumping for browser compatibility. Problem: solved. Move on.

Comment: The beauty with _.has is that you can use dot notation to check for deeply nested attributes, eg _.has(myObject, 'a.b.c');

Answer (score 224):

You can use this (but read the warning below):

```js
var x = {
  'key': 1
};

if ('key' in x) {
  console.log('has');
}
```

But **be warned**: `'constructor' in x` will return `true` even if `x` is an empty object - same for `'toString' in x`, and many others. It's better to use `Object.hasOwn(x, 'key')`.

Comment: Just to note, it works with 'objects' in narrow sense, so declared as {} or created using constructor, it doesn't accept arrays or primitives. Not that the OP has required it, but some other answers present techniques that are more broad (work with arrays, strings etc.)

Comment: @РСТȢѸФХѾЦЧШЩЪЫЬѢѤЮѦѪѨѬѠѺѮѰѲѴ thanks for pointing that out (the accepted answer does not go into details on why one should use the `in` operator or not. Also note that the `in` operator has excellent browser support `IE 5.5+, Chrome 1.0+, Firefox 1.0+, Safari 3.0+` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2920765/javascript-in-operator-compatibility

Comment: Operator `in` also checks against prototype properties, while `hasOwnProperty` iterates user-defined properties only. Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in

Comment: `'key' in x` **_do_** work with arrays. Proof: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33592385/if-0-in-array-is-this-even-legal

Answer (score 146):

**Note**: the following is nowadays largely obsolete thanks to strict mode, and `hasOwnProperty`. The correct solution is to use strict mode and to check for the presence of a property using `obj.hasOwnProperty`. This answer *predates* both these things, at least as widely implemented (yes, it is that old). Take the following as a historical note.

---

Bear in mind that `undefined` is (unfortunately) *not* a reserved word in JavaScript if you’re not using strict mode. Therefore, someone (someone else, obviously) could have the grand idea of redefining it, breaking your code.

A more robust method is therefore the following:

```
if (typeof(x.attribute) !== 'undefined')
```

On the flip side, this method is much more verbose and also slower. :-/

A common alternative is to ensure that `undefined` is *actually* undefined, e.g. by putting the code into a function which accepts an additional parameter, called `undefined`, that isn’t passed a value. To ensure that it’s not passed a value, you could just call it yourself immediately, e.g.:

```
(function (undefined) {
    … your code …
    if (x.attribute !== undefined)
        … mode code …
})();
```

Comment: Just curious, since `void 0` is defined to return the canonical `undefined`, could one do `x.attribute !== void 0`?

Comment: Brian: I'm no expert, but that sure seems like a clever way to get it right.

Comment: If the famous 'someone else' have redefined what undefined is, I think the best course of action would be to rewrite THAT code.

Comment: `undefined = (function () {}()); if (a.attribute !== undefined) 'foo';`

Comment: The best to have a solid undefined var, is to work within a closure, and have an unmatched function signature: `(function (undefined) { // undefined is actually undefined here })();`

Comment: Since ES5 strict mode, you cannot redefine undefined anymore, but you do have to remember to turn on the strict mode. :) Also, this answer does not test whether an object has some property, but test whether the property is undefined (which includes both existing and non-existing props).

Comment: @BrianM.Hunt your suggestion with `x.attribute !== void 0` (or `void(0)`) works great in my test.

Comment: @evanrmurphy Don't use that, it's seriously outdated (see note at the beginning of my answer).

Answer (score 61):

```
if (x.key !== undefined)
```

[Armin Ronacher](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19990/armin-ronacher) seems to have already [beat me to it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/135448/how-do-i-check-to-see-if-an-object-has-an-attribute-in-javascript#135466), but:

```
Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty = function(property) {
    return this[property] !== undefined;
};

x = {'key': 1};

if (x.hasOwnProperty('key')) {
    alert('have key!');
}

if (!x.hasOwnProperty('bar')) {
    alert('no bar!');
}
```

A safer, but slower solution, [as pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/135448/how-do-i-check-to-see-if-an-object-has-an-attribute-in-javascript#135568) by [Konrad Rudolph](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1968/konrad-rudolph) and [Armin Ronacher](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19990/armin-ronacher) would be:

```
Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty = function(property) {
    return typeof this[property] !== 'undefined';
};
```

Comment: I don't think that's good enough. `x.hasOwnProperty('toString') === true;`

Comment: Not asking to disagree, but to understand.  Is there any point where x.hasOwnProperty would return anything besides a boolean true or false?  If not, the code as posted should work every time.  I suppose maybe if the method were overridden, but then, relying on the result would never be reliable unless you know the overriding method.

Comment: I think we have a miscommunication. I mean that using your method, it would say that 'toString' is its own property, but it isn't.

Comment: `Object.prototype` already has a built-in, correct `hasOwnProperty`. Overwriting it with an incorrect implementation (1. Properties can have the value `undefined`, 2. This will give false positives for inherited properties) is just a hideously bad idea. Incorrect answers can and should be deleted. I don't know if you could do that back in Sep '08 [when you saw Resig's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/135448/how-do-i-check-if-an-object-has-a-property-in-javascript/135475#comment35250_136411), so commenting to suggest doing it now.

Answer (score 44):

Considering the following object in Javascript

```
const x = {key: 1};
```

You can use the `in` operator to check if the property exists on an object:

```
console.log("key" in x);
```

You can also loop through all the properties of the object using a `for - in` loop, and then check for the specific property:

```
for (const prop in x) {
    if (prop === "key") {
        //Do something
    }
}
```

You must consider if this object property is enumerable or not, because non-enumerable properties will not show up in a `for-in` loop. Also, if the enumerable property is shadowing a non-enumerable property of the prototype, it will not show up in [Internet Explorer 8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_8) and earlier.

If you’d like a list of all instance properties, whether enumerable or not, you can use

```
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(x);
```

This will return an array of names of all properties that exist on an object.

[Reflections](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Reflect) provide methods that can be used to interact with Javascript objects. The static `Reflect.has()` method works like the in operator as a function.

```
console.log(Reflect.has(x, 'key'));
// expected output: true

console.log(Reflect.has(x, 'key2'));
// expected output: false

console.log(Reflect.has(object1, 'toString'));
// expected output: true
```

Finally, you can use the typeof operator to directly check the data type of the object property:

```
if (typeof x.key === "undefined") {
    console.log("undefined");
}
```

If the property does not exist on the object, it will return the string undefined. Else it will return the appropriate property type. However, note that this is not always a valid way of checking if an object has a property or not, because you could have a property that is set to undefined, in which case, using `typeof x.key` would still return true (even though the key is still in the object).

Similarly, you can check if a property exists by comparing directly to the `undefined` Javascript property

```
if (x.key === undefined) {
    console.log("undefined");
}
```

This should work unless key was specifically set to `undefined` on the x object

Answer (score 33):

Let's cut through some confusion here. First, let's simplify by assuming `hasOwnProperty` already exists; this is true of the vast majority of current browsers in use.

`hasOwnProperty` returns true if the attribute name that is passed to it has been added to the object. It is entirely independent of the actual value assigned to it which may be exactly  `undefined`.

**Hence:**

```
var o = {}
o.x = undefined

var a = o.hasOwnProperty('x')  // a is true
var b = o.x === undefined // b is also true
```

**However:**

```
var o = {}

var a = o.hasOwnProperty('x')  // a is now false
var b = o.x === undefined // b is still true
```

The problem is what happens when an object in the prototype chain has an attribute with the value of undefined? `hasOwnProperty` will be false for it, and so will `!== undefined`. Yet, `for..in` will still list it in the enumeration.

The bottom line is there is no cross-browser way (since Internet Explorer doesn't expose `__prototype__`) to determine that a specific identifier has not been attached to an object or anything in its prototype chain.

Answer (score 32):

If you are searching for a property, then *"no"*. You want:

```
if ('prop' in obj) { }
```

In general, you should not care whether or not the property comes from the prototype or the object.

However, because you used 'key' in your sample code, it looks like you are treating the object as a hash, in which case your answer would make sense.  All of the hashes keys would be properties in the object, and you avoid the extra properties contributed by the prototype.

[John Resig's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/135448/how-do-i-check-if-an-object-has-a-specific-property-in-javascript/136411#136411) was very comprehensive, but I thought it wasn't clear. Especially with when to use "'prop' in obj".

Comment: Note that the `in` operator has excellent browser support `IE 5.5+, Chrome 1.0+, Firefox 1.0+, Safari 3.0+` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2920765/javascript-in-operator-compatibility

Comment: As pointed out in another comment regarding using the `in` operator: "it works with 'objects' in narrow sense, so declared as {} or created using constructor, it doesn't accept arrays or primitives. Not that the OP has required it, but some other answers present techniques that are more broad (work with arrays, strings etc.)"

Comment: Commenting cause I've been downvoted twice without comment.  But I still like my answer.  Perhaps whoever did so wanted a 'comprehensive' answer for all ways to test for all types of properties.. But my answer is conceptual and for that, succinct.  Re: Adrien Be, an unenumerable property is one that isn't meant for general user scope, so conceptually 'in' is fine ;)

Answer (score 26):

For testing simple objects, use:

```
if (obj[x] !== undefined)
```

If you don't know what object type it is, use:

```
if (obj.hasOwnProperty(x))
```

All other options are slower...

#### Details

A performance evaluation of 100,000,000 cycles under Node.js to the five options suggested by others here:

```
function hasKey1(k,o) { return (x in obj); }
function hasKey2(k,o) { return (obj[x]); }
function hasKey3(k,o) { return (obj[x] !== undefined); }
function hasKey4(k,o) { return (typeof(obj[x]) !== 'undefined'); }
function hasKey5(k,o) { return (obj.hasOwnProperty(x)); }
```

The evaluation tells us that unless we specifically want to check the object's prototype chain as well as the object itself, **we should not use the common form**:

```
if (X in Obj)...
```

**It is between 2 to 6 times slower depending on the use case**

```
hasKey1 execution time: 4.51 s
hasKey2 execution time: 0.90 s
hasKey3 execution time: 0.76 s
hasKey4 execution time: 0.93 s
hasKey5 execution time: 2.15 s
```

Bottom line, if your Obj is not necessarily a simple object and you wish to avoid checking the object's prototype chain and to ensure x is owned by Obj directly, use `if (obj.hasOwnProperty(x))...`.

Otherwise, when using a simple object and not being worried about the object's prototype chain, using `if (typeof(obj[x]) !== 'undefined')...` is the safest and fastest way.

If you use a simple object as a hash table and never do anything kinky, I would use `if (obj[x])...` as I find it much more readable.

Comment: Your middle paragraph implies that "IF (x in obj)" is good for checking the prototype chain, but your second to last paragraph implies that it checks the chain and is faster.  So is "syntax" the only reason to use (x in obj)?

Comment: "x in obj" is the only evaluated option that checks the prototype chain

Answer (score 20):

Yes it is :)  I think you can also do `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(x, 'key')` which should also work if `x` has a property called `hasOwnProperty` :)

But that tests for own properties.  If you want to check if it has an property that may also be inhered you can use `typeof x.foo != 'undefined'`.

Answer (score 18):

```js
if(x.hasOwnProperty("key")){
  // …
}
```

because

```js
if(x.key){
  // …
}
```

fails if `x.key` is falsy (for example, `x.key === ""`).

Answer (score 17):

You can also use [the ES6 `Reflect` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Reflect):

```
x = {'key': 1};
Reflect.has( x, 'key'); // returns true
```

Documentation on MDN for `Reflect.has` can be found [**here**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Reflect/has).

> The static `Reflect.has()` method works like the [in operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) as a function.

Answer (score 17):

Do not do this `object.hasOwnProperty(key))`. It's really bad because these methods may be shadowed by properties on the object in question - consider `{ hasOwnProperty: false }` - or, the object may be a null object `(Object.create(null))`.

The best way is to do `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(object, key)` or:

```
const has = Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty; // Cache the lookup once, in module scope.
console.log(has.call(object, key));
/* Or */
import has from 'has'; // https://www.npmjs.com/package/has
console.log(has(object, key));
```

Comment: I agree with this method and it should be the accepted answer as it is the safest way while maintaining performance! https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-prototype-builtins says "For example, it would be unsafe for a webserver to parse JSON input from a client and call hasOwnProperty directly on the resulting object, because a malicious client could send a JSON value like {"hasOwnProperty": 1} and cause the server to crash."

Answer (score 13):

OK, it looks like I had the right answer unless if you don't want inherited properties:

```
if (x.hasOwnProperty('key'))
```

Here are some other options to include inherited properties:

```
if (x.key) // Quick and dirty, but it does the same thing as below.

if (x.key !== undefined)
```

Comment: Caveat  x.hasOwnProperty('key') can be true whilst x.key !== undefined is not true.

Comment: For `var x = { key: false };` the `x.key` method would be incorrect.

Comment: if (x.key) is not correct as if x = {key:0}, it will not pass the checking.

Answer (score 10):

Another relatively simple way is using [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys). This returns an `array` which means you get all of the features of an array.

```
var noInfo = {};
var info = {something: 'data'};

Object.keys(noInfo).length //returns 0 or false
Object.keys(info).length //returns 1 or true
```

Although we are in a world with great browser support. Because this question is so old I thought I'd add this:
This is safe to use as of [JavaScript v1.8.5](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es5/#Object.keys).

Comment: Right but what if you wanted to know if info had a property with the name someotherthing? Which is think is what OP is looking for.

Comment: Then you would do `Object.keys(info).indexOf('someotherthing') !== -1`

Comment: What is *"JS v1.8.5"*? "JavaScript v1.8.5"*? It doesn't appear to match any [ECMAScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript) version (version 8 was released in 2017). [jQuery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery) 1.8 was released in 2012.

Comment: OK, [JavaScript 1.8.5](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Archive/Web/JavaScript/New_in_JavaScript/1.8.5) was released in 2011 with [Firefox 4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firefox_early_version_history#Firefox_4) (2011-03-22). The first version of [ECMAScript 5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript#5th_Edition) (linked to) is from 2009.

Comment: @hippietrail I think `Object.keys(info).includes('something')` is more ergonomic.

Comment: Example is given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66332561/7765316)

Answer (score 10):

JavaScript is now evolving and growing as it now has good and even efficient ways to check it.

Here are some easy ways to check if **object has a particular property**:

1. **Using `hasOwnProperty()`**

```js
const hero = {
  name: 'Batman'
};

hero.hasOwnProperty('name');     // => true
hero.hasOwnProperty('realName'); // => false
```

2. **Using keyword/operator `in`**

```js
const hero = {
  name: 'Batman'
};

'name' in hero;     // => true
'realName' in hero; // => false
```

3. **Comparing with `undefined` keyword**

```js
const hero = {
  name: 'Batman'
};

hero.name;     // => 'Batman'
hero.realName; // => undefined

// So consider this
hero.realName == undefined // => true (which means property does not exists in object)
hero.name == undefined // => false (which means that property exists in object)
```

For more information, check [here](https://dmitripavlutin.com/check-if-object-has-property-javascript/#:%7E:text=The%20first%20way%20is%20to,own%20properties%20of%20the%20object.).

Answer (score 8):

hasOwnProperty *"can be used to determine whether an object has the specified property as a direct property of that object; **unlike the in operator**, this method does not check down the object's prototype chain."*

So most probably, for what seems by your question, you don't want to use hasOwnProperty, which determines if the property exists as attached **directly to the object itself**,.

If you want to determine if the property exists in the prototype chain, you may want to use it like:

```
if (prop in object) { // Do something }
```

Comment: I get " Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'prop' in myObject"

Answer (score 5):

You can use the following approaches-

```
var obj = {a:1}
console.log('a' in obj)               // 1
console.log(obj.hasOwnProperty('a'))  // 2
console.log(Boolean(obj.a))         // 3
```

The difference between the following approaches are as follows-

1. In the first and third approach we are not just searching in object but its prototypal chain too. If the object does not have the property, but the property is present in its prototype chain it is going to give true.

```js
var obj = {
    a: 2,
    __proto__ : {b: 2}
}

console.log('b' in obj)
console.log(Boolean(obj.b))
```

2. The second approach will check only for its own properties. Example -

```js
var obj = {
    a: 2,
    __proto__ : {b: 2}
}

console.log(obj.hasOwnProperty('b'))
```

3. The difference between the first and the third is if there is a property which has value undefined the third approach is going to give false while first will give true.

```js
var obj = {
    b : undefined
}

console.log(Boolean(obj.b))
console.log('b' in obj);
```

Comment: `Boolean({b:''}.b) -> false`

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski yes it is supposed to give false, any falsy value in this case will return false

Answer (score 5):

Given *myObject* object and *“myKey”* as key name:

```
Object.keys(myObject).includes('myKey')
```

or

```
myObject.hasOwnProperty('myKey')
```

or

```
typeof myObject.myKey !== 'undefined'
```

The last was widely used, but (as pointed out in other answers and comments) it could also match on keys deriving from Object prototype.

Answer (score 5):

Now with **ECMAScript22** we can use [hasOwn](https://exploringjs.com/impatient-js/ch_objects.html#Object.hasOwn) instead of `hasOwnProperty` (Because this feature has pitfalls )

```
Object.hasOwn(obj, propKey)
```

Answer (score 4):

## Performance

Today 2020.12.17 I perform tests on MacOs HighSierra 10.13.6 on Chrome v87, Safari v13.1.2 and Firefox v83 for chosen solutions.

### Results

I compare only solutions A-F because they give valid result for all cased used in snippet in details section. For all browsers

- solution based on `in` (A) is fast or fastest
- solution (E) is fastest for chrome for big objects and fastest for firefox for small arrays if key not exists
- solution (F) is fastest (~ >10x than other solutions) for small arrays
- solutions (D,E) are quite fast
- solution based on losash `has` (B) is slowest

[image]

### Details

I perform 4 tests cases:

- when object has 10 fields and searched key exists - you can run it [HERE](https://jsbench.me/0skirxvkqa/1)
- when object has 10 fields and searched key not exists - you can run it [HERE](https://jsbench.me/1akis0ltq7/1)
- when object has 10000 fields and searched key exists - you can run it [HERE](https://jsbench.me/69kirynokp/1)
- when object has 10000 fields and searched key exists - you can run it [HERE](https://jsbench.me/nakis0mx5m/1)

Below snippet presents differences between solutions
[A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14664748/860099)
[B](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11315692/860099)
[C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40266120/860099)
[D](https://stackoverflow.com/q/135448/860099)
[E](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11315692/860099)
[F](https://stackoverflow.com/a/136411/860099)
[G](https://stackoverflow.com/a/135568/860099)
[H](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22740939/860099)
[I](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38332171/860099)
[J](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41184688/860099)
[K](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54196605/860099)

```js
// SO https://stackoverflow.com/q/135448/860099


// src: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14664748/860099
function A(x) {
  return 'key' in x
}

// src: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11315692/860099
function B(x) {
  return _.has(x, 'key')
}

// src: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40266120/860099
function C(x) {
  return Reflect.has( x, 'key')
}

// src: https://stackoverflow.com/q/135448/860099
function D(x) {
  return x.hasOwnProperty('key')
}

// src: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11315692/860099
function E(x) {
  return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(x, 'key')
}

// src: https://stackoverflow.com/a/136411/860099
function F(x) {
  function hasOwnProperty(obj, prop) {
      var proto = obj.__proto__ || obj.constructor.prototype;
      return (prop in obj) &&
          (!(prop in proto) || proto[prop] !== obj[prop]);
  }
  return hasOwnProperty(x,'key')
}

// src: https://stackoverflow.com/a/135568/860099
function G(x) {
  return typeof(x.key) !== 'undefined'
}

// src: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22740939/860099
function H(x) {
  return x.key !== undefined
}

// src: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38332171/860099
function I(x) {
  return !!x.key
}

// src: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41184688/860099
function J(x) {
  return !!x['key']
}

// src: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54196605/860099
function K(x) {
  return Boolean(x.key)
}


// --------------------
// TEST
// --------------------

let x1 = {'key': 1};
let x2 = {'key': "1"};
let x3 = {'key': true};
let x4 = {'key': []};
let x5 = {'key': {}};
let x6 = {'key': ()=>{}};
let x7 = {'key': ''};
let x8 = {'key': 0};
let x9 = {'key': false};
let x10= {'key': undefined};
let x11= {'nokey': 1};



let b= x=> x ? 1:0;

console.log('  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11');

[A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K ].map(f=> {  
  console.log(
    `${f.name} ${b(f(x1))} ${b(f(x2))} ${b(f(x3))} ${b(f(x4))} ${b(f(x5))} ${b(f(x6))} ${b(f(x7))} ${b(f(x8))} ${b(f(x9))} ${b(f(x10))}  ${b(f(x11))} `
  )})
  
console.log('\nLegend: Columns (cases)');
console.log('1.  key = 1 ');
console.log('2.  key = "1" ');
console.log('3.  key = true ');
console.log('4.  key = [] ');
console.log('5.  key = {} ');
console.log('6.  key = ()=>{} ');
console.log('7.  key = "" ');
console.log('8.  key = 0 ');
console.log('9.  key = false ');
console.log('10. key = undefined ');
console.log('11. no-key ');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.20/lodash.min.js" integrity="sha512-90vH1Z83AJY9DmlWa8WkjkV79yfS2n2Oxhsi2dZbIv0nC4E6m5AbH8Nh156kkM7JePmqD6tcZsfad1ueoaovww==" crossorigin="anonymous"> </script>
  
This shippet only presents functions used in performance tests - it not perform tests itself!
```

And here are example results for chrome

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here is another option for a specific case. :)

If you want to test for a member on an object and want to know if it has been set to something other than:

- ''
- false
- null
- undefined
- 0
  ...

then you can use:

```
var foo = {};
foo.bar = "Yes, this is a proper value!";
if (!!foo.bar) {
    // member is set, do something
}
```

Comment: Compact and convenient

Comment: A linter won't like this: https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-extra-boolean-cast

Answer (score 3):

**some easier and short options depending on the specific use case:**

1. to check if the property exists, regardless of value, use the [in operator ("a" in b)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in)
2. to check a property value from a variable, use [bracket notation (obj[v])](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#bracket_notation)
3. to check a property value as truthy, use [optional
   chaining (?.)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)
4. to check a property value boolean, use [double-not / bang-bang / (!!)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_NOT#double_not_!!)
5. to set a default value for null / undefined check, use [nullish coalescing operator (??)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator)
6. to set a default value for falsey value check, use short-circuit [logical OR operator (||)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator)

run the code snippet to see results:

```js
let obj1 = {prop:undefined};
console.log(1,"prop" in obj1);
console.log(1,obj1?.prop);

let obj2 = undefined;
//console.log(2,"prop" in obj2); would throw because obj2 undefined
console.log(2,"prop" in (obj2 ?? {}))
console.log(2,obj2?.prop);

let obj3 = {prop:false};
console.log(3,"prop" in obj3);
console.log(3,!!obj3?.prop);

let obj4 = {prop:null};
let look = "prop"
console.log(4,"prop" in obj4);
console.log(4,obj4?.[look]);

let obj5 = {prop:true};
console.log(5,"prop" in obj5);
console.log(5,obj5?.prop === true);

let obj6 = {otherProp:true};
look = "otherProp"
console.log(6,"prop" in obj6);
console.log(6,obj6.look); //should have used bracket notation

let obj7 = {prop:""};
console.log(7,"prop" in obj7);
console.log(7,obj7?.prop || "empty");
```

I see very few instances where `hasOwn` is used properly, especially given its [inheritance issues](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty#direct_vs._inherited_properties)

Answer (score 3):

I had a hard time understanding the difference between hasOwn and hasOwnProperty even though there are 30 answers trying to explain this.  Here's a runnable snippet, so you can see for yourself how it behaves.

```js
const object1 = {
  prop: 'exists'
};
object1.property1 = 42;

// the following as you might expect output true
console.log(object1.hasOwnProperty('property1'));
console.log(Object.hasOwn(object1,"prop"));
console.log(Object.hasOwn(object1,"property1"));

// the following might surpize you, they output false
console.log(Object.hasOwnProperty(object1,"prop"));
console.log(Object.hasOwnProperty(object1,"property1"));

// the following as you rightfully expect output false
console.log(object1.hasOwnProperty('toString'));
console.log(Object.hasOwn(object1,"toString"));
console.log(Object.hasOwnProperty(object1,"toString"));

console.log(object1.hasOwnProperty('hasOwnProperty'));
console.log(Object.hasOwn(object1,"hasOwnProperty"));
console.log(Object.hasOwnProperty(object1,"hasOwnProperty"));
```

Answer (score 2):

An ECMAScript 6 solution with reflection. Create a wrapper like:

```
/**
Gets an argument from array or object.
The possible outcome:
- If the key exists the value is returned.
- If no key exists the default value is returned.
- If no default value is specified an empty string is returned.
@param obj    The object or array to be searched.
@param key    The name of the property or key.
@param defVal Optional default version of the command-line parameter [default ""]
@return The default value in case of an error else the found parameter.
*/
function getSafeReflectArg( obj, key, defVal) {
   "use strict";
   var retVal = (typeof defVal === 'undefined' ? "" : defVal);
   if ( Reflect.has( obj, key) ) {
       return Reflect.get( obj, key);
   }
   return retVal;
}  // getSafeReflectArg
```

Comment: Is this the best way to do it when you're targeting >= ES6?

Comment: Imho it is the shortest and most simple answer, but maybe not the fastest in execution code. But speed is not an issue (anymore).

Comment: Why post [the same answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40266120/1697459) twice? You could just upvote the existing one...?

Answer (score 2):

There is a method, "hasOwnProperty", that exists on an object, but it's not recommended to call this method directly, because it might be sometimes that the object is null or some property exist on the object like: `{ hasOwnProperty: false }`

So a better way would be:

```js
// Good
var obj = {"bar": "here bar desc"}
console.log(Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, "bar"));

// Best
const has = Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty; // Cache the lookup once, in module scope.
console.log(has.call(obj, "bar"));
```

Answer (score 2):

Showing how to use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30533729/7765316)

```
const object= {key1: 'data', key2: 'data2'};

Object.keys(object).includes('key1') //returns true
```

We can use `indexOf` as well, I prefer [includes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45264728/7765316)

Answer (score 2):

**TLDR: In TypeScript use `in`, for now**

In TypeScript only `in` operator is type-guarding, `Object.hasOwn` and `obj.hasOwnProperty` don't provide type checking information.
Proposal for this functionality is still in stage: https://github.com/tc39/proposal-accessible-object-hasownproperty

```
if (Object.hasOwn(error, 'message')) {
  console.log(error.message); // Property 'message' does not exist on type 'object'.ts(2339)
}
```

```
if ('message' in error) {
  console.log(error.message); // good
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the method `object.hasOwnProperty(property)`. It returns true if the object has the property and false if the object doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

The **hasOwnProperty()** method returns a boolean indicating whether the object has the specified property as its own property (as opposed to inheriting it).

```
const object1 = {};
object1.property1 = 42;

console.log(object1.hasOwnProperty('property1'));
// expected output: true

console.log(object1.hasOwnProperty('toString'));
// expected output: false

console.log(object1.hasOwnProperty('hasOwnProperty'));
// expected output: false
```

[Know more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty)

Answer (score 0):

Don't over-complicate things when you can do:

```
var isProperty =  (objectname.keyname || "") ? true : false;
```

It Is simple and clear for most cases...

Comment: The most simplest one is var isProperty =  !!objectname.keyname;

Comment: If the object is as follows `const objectName = { keyname: false };` it should return true, since `keyname` is a property of `objectname`. But since the value is false it would return false with this logic.

Answer (score 0):

### A Better approach for iterating on object's own properties:

If you want to iterate on object's properties without using `hasOwnProperty()` check,
use `for(let key of Object.keys(stud)){}` method:

```
for(let key of Object.keys(stud)){
  console.log(key); // will only log object's Own properties
}
```

full Example and comparison with `for-in with hasOwnProperty()`

```
function Student() {
  this.name = "nitin";
}

Student.prototype = {
  grade: 'A'
}

let stud = new Student();

// for-in approach
for(let key in stud){
  if(stud.hasOwnProperty(key)){
    console.log(key); // only outputs "name"
  }
} 

//Object.keys() approach
for(let key of Object.keys(stud)){
  console.log(key);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

x?.key returns 1 if x.key exists, otherwise undefined