# How do I check in JavaScript if a value exists at a certain array index?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Will this work for testing whether a value at position `index` exists or not, or is there a better way:

```
if(arrayName[index]==""){
     // do stuff
}
```

Comment: Please note, not wanting to check if the whole array is empty, just a certain location which has the index value of "index"

Comment: The title can be improved by saying "How do I check in JavaScript if a value exists at a certain array index".

Answer (score 766, accepted):

Conceptually, arrays in JavaScript contain `array.length` elements, starting with `array[0]` up until `array[array.length - 1]`.  An array element with index `i` is defined to be part of the array if `i` is between `0` and `array.length - 1` inclusive.  If i is not in this range it's not in the array.

So by concept, arrays are linear, starting with zero and going to a maximum, without any mechanism for having "gaps" inside that range where no entries exist.  To find out if a value exists at a given position index (where index is 0 or a positive integer), you literally just use

```
if (i >= 0 && i < array.length) {
  // it is in array
}
```

Now, under the hood, JavaScript engines almost certainly won't allocate array space linearly and contiguously like this, as it wouldn't make much sense in a dynamic language and it would be inefficient for certain code.  They're probably hash tables or some hybrid mixture of strategies, and undefined ranges of the array probably aren't allocated their own memory.  Nonetheless, JavaScript the language wants to present arrays of `array.length` *n* as having *n* members and they are named *0* to *n - 1*, and anything in this range is part of the array.

What you probably want, however, is to know if a value in an array is *actually something defined* - that is, it's not `undefined`.  Maybe you even want to know if it's defined and *not `null`*.  It's possible to add members to an array without ever setting their value: for example, if you add array values by increasing the `array.length` property, any new values will be `undefined`.

To determine if a given value is something meaningful, or has been defined.  That is, **not** `undefined`, or `null`:

```
if (typeof array[index] !== 'undefined') {
```

or

```
if (typeof array[index] !== 'undefined' && array[index] !== null) {
```

Interestingly, because of JavaScript's comparison rules, my last example can be optimised down to this:

```
if (array[index] != null) {
  // The == and != operators consider null equal to only null or undefined
}
```

Comment: It's highly likely that the OP knows what sort of array s/he's dealing with, but just for completeness: *array-like* objects also typically contain a `length` property, in which case the later two examples are more appropriate.

Comment: Thanks Justin .... I am actually quite green between the ears about JS, so this is all helpful info

Comment: The top example is also applicable to array-like objects.  The definition of an array-like object is an object with property `obj.length`, and properties numbered `0` to *obj.length-1*.

Comment: you can always replace `foo !== 'undefined' && foo !== null` with just `foo != null`

Comment: You can actually have holes is a javascript array... someone could potentially use the delete keyword on an index of the array. In this case the values do not shift, and you are left with a missing index.

Comment: @TheComposer according to the language the size of an array in Javascript is defined by array.length, and the array is said to comprise all elements from `0` to `array.length - 1`.  Not all of these values will be *defined* values though.  If you use the delete keyword on an array member it will set that member back to being undefined, just like if you extend an array by incrementing its array.length parameter, the new values will start as undefined.  In reality, Javascript implementations will probably optimise array storage and some or all undefined values may occupy no memory.

Comment: Thank you!  In the process, I just ended up setting the array to a var and referencing element 0.  But, it pointed me in the right direction, regardless.

Comment: Is there less expensive array.length? Because array.length iterates through each element. We only need to know if the array has at least 1 element.

Comment: array.length does not iterate over anything, it's just a single number.

Comment: I really liked theway you explained the answer. Thums up!

Comment: This answer doesn't cover cases where an array index is not set.  `new Array(1)[0] === undefined` but the value is empty.  `[undefined][0] === undefined` but the value is set; the array *has* a value.  The only *perfect* answer is using `in` or `hasOwnProperty()`--`idx in array` or `array.hasOwnProperty(idx)`--per this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39171620/3120446

Comment: The result of `in` does reveal the internal treatment of arrays as if they are objects (hash tables) instead of literal arrays, and it is interesting the way that `(i in a)` can be true or false even when the value `a[i]` in both cases is `undefined`.  In my opinion, if you are using it as an array the distinction between a value being undefined because you haven't ever set a value to that particular index and a value being undefined because you've explicitly set it to undefined is not important, but if it is, `in` can be used.

Comment: This is the highest voted wrong answer I have ever encountered on SE. I hope the author here will read https://remysharp.com/2018/06/26/an-adventure-in-sparse-arrays or any other article on sparse arrays and update this answer.

Comment: Despite the unfriendly tone of your comment I've addressed this in my answer now, though I haven't included the trick for distinguishing a value set to undefined from a value which is undefined because it has never been defined.  It's an interesting example of getting some underlying information out of Javascript, though with questionable practical use - IMHO if your code relies on distinguishing "undefined because reason A" from "undefined because reason B" from each other, it arguably should be reworked to actually express these as explicit values.

Answer (score 352):

Can't we just do this:

```
if(arrayName.length > 0){   
    //or **if(arrayName.length)**
    //this array is not empty 
}else{
   //this array is empty
}
```

Comment: The question was about how to test if a *particular index* of an array exists or not.

Comment: Would `if(arrayName.length) {...` make any difference?

Comment: Why so many upvotes? This clearly does not answer the question.

Comment: `if(arrayName.length) {...` fails on `null`

Comment: this fails with `[undefined, undefined]` which is an array with length = 2.

Comment: It also fails on: ```[""]```

Comment: @algiogia because when you do a google search on 'javascript array empty', this question is one of the top results.

Comment: @Fortega we are talking about the upvotes to the wrong answer, not about the question

Comment: @algiogia me too

Comment: @algiogia This "wrong" answer of the OP is the exact answer to the question in the title. If you do a google search you find this page and then you realize that there is a difference between the OP and the question in the title. If you  scroll down you find this and you're happy.

Comment: Yes this answer completely misses OP question and appears in one of the first results on Google. Most answer expect the first one missed the context of the question which is to find if an array Index is empty or not, not the whole array!

Answer (score 45):

Using only `.length` is not safe and will cause an error in some browsers. Here is a better solution:

```
if(array && array.length){   
   // not empty 
} else {
   // empty
}
```

or, we can use:

```
Object.keys(__array__).length
```

Comment: «Please note, not wanting to check if the whole array is empty, just a certain location which has the index value of "index"»

Comment: nice, short and simple answer for those who want to check the whole array

Comment: This answer completely misses OP question, the question is to find if an array Index is empty or not, not the whole array!

Answer (score 26):

```
if(!arrayName[index]){
     // do stuff
}
```

Comment: This would also do stuff if the array value exists but is 0, null, "", etc.

Comment: Thomas is right; however, this is sufficient for many cases (which you should probably enumerate).

Comment: by far the simplest way

Answer (score 9):

```
if(arrayName.length > index && arrayName[index] !== null) {
    //arrayName[index] has a value
}
```

Comment: @thomasrutter I'm having trouble coming up with a way it would be possible to end up with an array element that is undefined.

Comment: Hmmm, does (myarray[1] = undefinedvariable) work?  Or just (myarray[1] = undefined)?

Comment: @thomasrutter both of those would throw an exception, no? (undefinedvariable is undefined)

Comment: You can test it for yourself using something like Firebug.  In Javascript, reading the value of an undefined variable does not throw an exception - it returns the undefined value.

Comment: @thomasrutter you're wrong in your first comment. `x == null` will only ever be true for null or undefined, nothing else. Likewise, `x != null` will be true for anything that is neither null or undefined. Unless you specifically need to look for undefined, just lean in to the implicit conversion goodness.

Comment: @macke you're right: `x == null` will only match null or undefined.  I'm going to edit my answer, thanks.

Answer (score 8):

**Short and universal approach**

If you want to check any array if it has falsy values (like false, undefined, null or empty strings) you can just use *every()* method like this:

```
array.every(function(element) {return !!element;}); // returns true or false
```

For example:

```
['23', null, 2, {key: 'value'}].every(function(element) {return !!element;}); // returns false

['23', '', 2, {key: 'value'}].every(function(element) {return !!element;}); // returns false

['23', true, 2, {key: 'value'}].every(function(element) {return !!element;}); // returns true
```

If you need to get a first index of falsy value, you can do it like this:

```
let falsyIndex; 

if(!['23', true, 2, null, {key: 'value'}].every(function(element, index) {falsyIndex = index; return !!element;})) {
  console.log(falsyIndex);
} // logs 3
```

If you just need to check a falsy value of an array for a given index you can just do it like this:

```
if (!!array[index]) {
  // array[index] is a correct value
}
else {
  // array[index] is a falsy value
}
```

Answer (score 7):

```
if(typeof arr ==='object' && arr instanceof Array ){
   if(!arr.length){
      println 'empty'
   }else{
      printn 'not Empty'
   }

}else{
   println 'Null'
}
```

If you mean by 'Null' -> Its elements are null or equals to '' , in this case : Check if the array is empty after filtering all 'null' elements

```
if(!arr.clean().length){return 'is null'}
```

Of course ,Add **Clean**  method before :

```
Array.prototype.clean=function(){return this.filter(function(e){return (typeof  e !=='undefined')&&(e!= null)&&(e!='')})}
```

Answer (score 7):

It depends on what you mean with "empty".

When you attempt to get the value of a property on an object which has no property with that name, you will get the value `undefined`.

That's what happens with sparse arrays: not all indices between `0` and `array.length-1` exist.

So you could check if `array[index] === undefined`.

However, the property `index` could exist with an `undefined` value. If you want to filter out this case, you can use the `in` operator or `hasOwnProperty`, as described in [How do I check if an object has a property in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/135448/1529630)

```
index in array;
array.hasOwnProperty(index);
```

If you want consider an existing property with an `undefined` or `null` value to not exist, you can use the loose comparison `array[index] == undefined` or `array[index] == null`.

If you know the array is not sparse, you could compare `index` with `array.length`. But to be safe, you may want to ensure that `index` really is an array index, see [Check if property name is array index](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38163612/1529630)

Comment: This is the only answer which properly distingushes between unset array items (which don't have any value) and items which are set to the undefined value. The 2 states are blurred by the fact that accessing an unset array item returns undefined, but they are different.

Comment: Use hasOwnProperty when you have an array with potentially unset values (different from undefined or null).

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend creating a function like this:

```
function isEmptyEl(array, i) {
   return !(array[i]);
}
```

You could call it like this:

```
if (isEmptyEl(arrayName, indexVal)) {
   console.log('arrayName[' + indexVal + '] is empty');
}
```

Forcing the developer to adhere to the isEmptyEl interface will catch input errors such as an undefined arrayName or indexVal variables.

(It's generally good practice to program defensively when programming in Javascript.)

You would get an error thrown like this if arrayName was not defined:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: arrayName is not defined
    at <anonymous>:2:15
    at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateOn (<anonymous>:895:140)
    at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateAndWrap (<anonymous>:828:34)
    at Object.InjectedScript.evaluate (<anonymous>:694:21)
```

Similar results for an undefined indexVal.

You get an error if the array or index values do not exist.

For valid input, you'll only get a true if arrayName[indexVal] is any of the following:

- null
- undefined
- NaN
- empty string
- 0
- false

Answer (score 2):

I would like to point out something a few seem to have missed: namely it is possible to have an "empty" array position in the middle of your array. Consider the following:

```
let arr = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

delete arr[3]

console.log(arr)      // [0, 1, 2, empty, 4, 5]

console.log(arr[3])   // undefined
```

The natural way to check would then be to see whether the array member is undefined, I am unsure if other ways exists

```
if (arr[index] === undefined) {
  // member does not exist
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## Real detection: `in` operator

This question age is about 10 years and it is surprising that nobody mention about this yet - however some people see the problem when we use `delete` operator (e.g [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50480585/860099)). This is also a little bit counter intuitive solution but the `in` operator which works in 'object world' can also work with arrays (because we can look on array indexes like on 'keys'...). In this way we can detect and distinct between `undefined` array value and value (index) removed by `delete`

```
if(index in arrayName) {
   // do stuff 
}
```

```js
let arr = [0, 1, 2, 3, null, undefined,6]

delete arr[2]; // we delete element at index=2

if(2 in arr) console.log('You will not see this because idx 2 was deleted');
if(5 in arr) console.log('This is element arr[5]:', arr[5]);



// Whole array and indexes bigger than arr.length:
for(let i=0; i<=9; i++) {
  let val = (i in arr) ? arr[i] : 'empty'
  let bound = i<arr.length ? '' : '(out of range)'
  console.log(`${i} value: `, val, bound);
}


console.log('Look on below aray on chrome console (not in SO snippet console)');
console.log('typeof arr:', typeof arr);
console.log(arr);
```

Chrome console reveals some info about snippet array with deleted index 2 - this index actually not exists at all (!!!) (same way as key is removed from object). What is also interesting here array is viewd as key-value pairs (we even see 'length' key). It is also interesting that `typeof arr` is Object (!!!), the `delete` and `in` operator works like for JS objects
(also square brackets notation `arr[idx]` and `obj[key]` is similar) - so it looks like array is some special JS object in the core.

[image]

To get similar effect without `delete` define array as follows

```
[0, 1,, 3, null, undefined, 6] // pay attention to double comma: ",,"
```

Answer (score 1):

**OK,** let's first see what would happens if an array value not exist in JavaScript, so if we have an array like below:

```
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
```

and now we check if **6** is there at index **5** or not:

```
arr[5];
```

and we get 
`undefined`...

So that's basically give us the answer, the **best way** to check if undefined, so something like this:

```
if("undefined" === typeof arrayName[index]) {
  //array value is not there...
}
```

It's better **NOT** doing this in this case:

```
if(!arrayName[index]) {
  //Don't check like this..
}
```

Because imagine we have this array:

```
const arr = [0, 1, 2];
```

and we do:

```
if(!arr[0]) {
  //This get passed, because in JavaScript 0 is falsy
}
```

So as you see, even **0** is there, it doesn't get recognised, there are few other things which can do the same and make you application buggy, so be careful, I list them all down:

1. **undefined**: if the value is not defined and it's `undefined`
2. **null**: if it's null, for example if a DOM element not exists...
3. **empty string**: `''`
4. **0**: number zero
5. **NaN**: not a number
6. **false**

Answer (score 0):

try this if array[index] is null

```
if (array[index] != null)
```

Answer (score 0):

With Lodash, you can do:

```
if(_.has(req,'documents')){
      if (req.documents.length)
      _.forEach(req.documents, function(document){
        records.push(document);
      });
} else {
}
```

`if(_.has(req,'documents'))` is to check whether our request object has a property named `documents` and if it has that prop, the next `if (req.documents.length)` is to validate if it is not an empty array, so the other stuffs like `forEach` can be proceeded.

Answer (score 0):

To check if it has never been defined or if it was deleted:

```
if(typeof arrayName[index]==="undefined"){
     //the index is not in the array
}
```

also works with associative arrays and arrays where you deleted some index

To check if it was never been defined, was deleted OR is a null or logical empty value (NaN, empty string, false):

```
if(typeof arrayName[index]==="undefined"||arrayName[index]){
     //the index is not defined or the value an empty value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue using laravel datatables. I was storing a JSON value called `properties` in an activity log and wanted to show a button based on this value being empty or not.

Well, datatables was interpreting this as an array if it was empty, and an object if it was not, therefore, the following solution worked for me:

```
render: function (data, type, full) {
    if (full.properties.length !== 0) {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

An object does not have a length property.

Answer (score 0):

I think this decision is appropriate for guys who prefer the declarative functional programming over the imperative OOP or the procedural. If your question is *"**Is there some values inside?** (a truthy or a falsy value)"* you can use `.some` method to validate the values inside.

```
[].some(el => el || !el);
```

- It isn't perfect but it doesn't require to apply any extra function containing the same logic, like `function isEmpty(arr) { ... }`.
- It still sounds better than *"Is it zero length?"* when we do this `[].length` resulting to `0` which is dangerous in some cases.
- Or even this `[].length > 0` saying *"Is its length greater than zero?"*

Advanced examples:

```
[    ].some(el => el || !el); // false
[null].some(el => el || !el); // true
[1, 3].some(el => el || !el); // true
```

Answer (score 0):

when you create empty array values ARE NOT undefined, they are EMPTY

```
var arr = new Array(10); // (10) [empty × 10]
```

but when you get item by index receive undefined

```
arr[0]; // undefined
```

so you can't know by === comparing if they are undefined or empty

we can make it by using JSON.stringify, converting whole array it replaces empty values with null

```
JSON.stringify(arr); // "[null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null]"
JSON.stringify(arr[0]); // but for single item it returns undefined
```

so real check for empty value:

```
arr[0] !== null && JSON.stringify(arr.map(item => !item)).slice(1, -1).split(',')[0] === 'null'
```

1. compare item with null (should be not equal)
2. map array removing `false` instead existing values (ensure stringified structure to be comma-separated without redundant commas)
3. JSON.stringify array
4. remove brackets from string
5. split into array by comma
6. compare with `null`

Answer (score -1):

You can use Loadsh library to do this more efficiently, like:

if you have an array named "pets", for example:

```
var pets = ['dog', undefined, 'cat', null];

console.log(_.isEmpty(pets[1])); // true
console.log(_.isEmpty(pets[3])); // true
console.log(_.isEmpty(pets[4])); // false

_.map( pets, (pet, index) => { console.log(index + ': ' + _.isEmpty(pet) ) });
```

To check all array values for null or undefined values:

```js
var pets = ['dog', undefined, 'cat', null];

console.log(_.isEmpty(pets[1])); // true
console.log(_.isEmpty(pets[3])); // true
console.log(_.isEmpty(pets[4])); // false

_.map( pets, (pet, index) => { console.log(index + ': ' + _.isEmpty(pet) ) });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

Check more examples in http://underscorejs.org/

Comment: `fn(){}` is a syntax error, and it's not clear at all how this helps checking whether an array item exists at a certain index or not.