# Check if array is empty or null

Tags: jquery, arrays, is-empty

I would like to know how to check if an array is empty or null in jQuery. I tried `array.length === 0` but it didn't work. It did not throw any error either.

This is the code:

```
var album_text = new Array();

$("input[name='album_text[]']").each(function(){
  if( $(this).val() &&  $(this).val() != '') {
    album_text.push($(this).val());
  }
});
if (album_text.length === 0) {
  $('#error_message').html("Error");
}

else {
  // send data
}
```

Comment: The same way as in "normal JavaScript":
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2672380/how-do-i-check-if-a-javascript-array-value-is-empty-or-null

Comment: @Julien, I tried all of those solutions listed in that thread before starting this thread. None of them worked somehow.

Comment: Can we get some more code for context? Surrounding JavaScript, HTML? Are you sure that `$("input[name='album_text[]']")` is actually returning elements?

Comment: @JulienSchmidt: the question you linked to is about checking if an array *value* is empty, not the entire array.

Answer (score 190, accepted):

As long as your selector is actually working, I see nothing wrong with your code that checks the length of the array.  That should do what you want.  There are a lot of ways to clean up your code to be simpler and more readable.  Here's a cleaned up version with notes about what I cleaned up.

```
var album_text = [];

$("input[name='album_text[]']").each(function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    if (value) {
        album_text.push(value);
    }
});
if (album_text.length === 0) {
    $('#error_message').html("Error");
}

else {
  //send data
}
```

Some notes on what you were doing and what I changed.

1. `$(this)` is always a valid jQuery object so there's no reason to ever check `if ($(this))`.  It may not have any DOM objects inside it, but you can check that with `$(this).length` if you need to, but that is not necessary here because the `.each()` loop wouldn't run if there were no items so `$(this)` inside your `.each()` loop will always be something.
2. It's inefficient to use $(this) multiple times in the same function.  Much better to get it once into a local variable and then use it from that local variable.
3. It's recommended to initialize arrays with `[]` rather than `new Array()`.
4. `if (value)` when value is expected to be a string will both protect from `value == null`, `value == undefined` and `value == ""` so you don't have to do `if (value && (value != ""))`.  You can just do: `if (value)` to check for all three empty conditions.
5. `if (album_text.length === 0)` will tell you if the array is empty as long as it is a valid, initialized array (which it is here).

What are you trying to do with this selector `$("input[name='album_text[]']")`?

Comment: @MaciekSemik - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/does-it-matter-which-equals-operator-vs-i-use-in-javascript-comparisons.  I always use strict equality (`===`) unless I specifically want to allow a type conversion.  It's a good habit to get into.

Answer (score 84):

User JQuery is EmptyObject to check whether array is contains elements or not.

```
var testArray=[1,2,3,4,5];
var testArray1=[];
console.log(jQuery.isEmptyObject(testArray)); //false
console.log(jQuery.isEmptyObject(testArray1)); //true
```

Comment: Much more reliable than checking the length, especially if your variable can also be an object (with objects, length do not work to check if empty).

Comment: This is the more appropriate answer in my opinion.

Comment: `isEmptyObject` always returns `false` if `Array.prototype` is extended, e.g. `Array.prototype.someFunction = function () {};` - even if the array is empty. Note that some frameworks (e.g. Ember.js) extend Array prototype by default.

Comment: Be careful with `isEmptyObject`!For jQuery 1.8.3 `jQuery.isEmptyObject([])` returns `false`, but for jQuery 1.11.3 it returns `true`. Actually, [jQuery documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.isEmptyObject/) says **The argument should always be a plain JavaScript Object as other types of object (DOM elements, primitive strings/numbers, host objects) may not give consistent results across browsers.** Sorry, didn't see @rhinoxi 's answer.

Answer (score 9):

I think it is dangerous to use $.isEmptyObject from jquery to check whether the array is empty, as @jesenko mentioned. I just met that problem.

In the [isEmptyObject doc](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.isEmptyObject/), it mentions:

> The argument should always be a plain JavaScript Object

which you can determine by `$.isPlainObject`. The return of `$.isPlainObject([])` is false.

Answer (score 8):

You should check for `''` (empty string) before pushing into your array. Your array has elements that are empty strings. Then your `album_text.length === 0` will work just fine.

Comment: Please see the updated the code. I added this code `if( $(this).val() &&  $(this).val() != '') ` yet it does not work.

Answer (score 4):

```
/*
  Basic Checking with undefined array for Jquery Array
*/
if (typeof myArray !== 'undefined' && myArray.length > 0) {
    console.log('myArray is not empty.');
}else{
    console.log('myArray is empty.');
}
```