# Several functions attached to a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a button called "run" and there are 3 fucntions that happen when this run button is clicked. However i think because there are so many functions firing when this button is clicked, it starts to mess up on the 3rd function which does not seem to work.

the first function checks to see if any div that starts with the name "Drop" has the class "wrong", if so then it shows a dialog box appears

code:

```
    $("#run").click(function() {
  if ($("[id^='Drop']").hasClass("wrong")) {
    $("#Incorrect").dialog("open");
  }
});
```

the second function checks to see if any of the Divs starting with "Drop" are empty, if there is an empty Div it will show the dialog box

code:

```
$("#run").click(function(){       
    if ($("[id^='Drop']").is(":empty")){
     $("#Wrong2").dialog("open");
    };
});
```

the third function will play a video if there are no divs with the class wrong AND if there are no empty divs.

```
$("#run").click(function(){       
    if ($("[id^='Drop']").not(":empty") && $("[id^='Drop']").not(".wrong")){
     $('#map1').get(0).play();
    };
});
```

Now both the 1st and 2nd functions are working correctly, however function 3 is not working. The video just ignores the conditions and plays anyway. I need it to only play when the conditions have been met

I know this is a horrible way of setting this all up, I've only recently started working with jquery so if anyone could help me in with i would very much appreciate it.

Comment: Just wondering: is there a reason why you need to use 3 separate onclick events instead of doing everything in one place?

Comment: I've tried getting it all on one place but could never get it to work :(

Comment: If you could create a fiddle I could try an fix it for you.

Comment: `not` does not return a boolean value, it returns a jquery object so both conditions are going to always evaluate to truthy values. Check their lengths `.not(...).length` or use `is` and combine `.is(".wrong:empty")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it may be as simple as this :

```
$('#run').click(function(){
    var $drops = $("[id^='Drop']");
    if($drops.is('.wrong')) {
        $('#Incorrect').dialog('open');
    }
    else if($drops.is(':empty')) {
        $('#Wrong2').dialog('open');  
    }
    else {
        $('#map1').get(0).play();
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the world of confusing javascript object evaluation!

While regularly, an empty array is falsy, `[] && []` (which is what happens when neither of those statements are true) evaluates to true because there are, in fact, two objects.

I'd instead use one of [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2672380/how-do-i-check-if-a-javascript-array-value-is-empty-or-null) methods to decide if the two arrays returned from the jQuery selectors are empty or not, then your code will work as intended.

This should work:

```
if ($("[id^='Drop']").not(":empty").length === 0 && $("[id^='Drop']").not(".wrong").length === 0){
   $('#map1').get(0).play();
};
```

Comment: I tried this and the video no longer plays whenever you click on the run button, however it now does not play full stop :(. if its not empty and hasn't got the  class wrong it should play

Comment: Could you post a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) with a boiled down example of your code? it'll make it much easier to track what's wrong.

Comment: I ask because I think we've got it backwards- you might need to change `===` to `!==` for one or both of your predicates.

Answer (score 0):

Please put everything under a single click event and change this

```
 if ($("[id^='Drop']").not(":empty") && $("[id^='Drop']").not(".wrong")){
     $('#map1').get(0).play();
```

to this

```
 $("div[id^='Drop']:not(:empty)").length && !$("div[id^='Drop']").hasClass('wrong') && $('#map1').get(0).play();
```

Here is a demo: https://jsfiddle.net/erkaner/u4q9435q/1/

Comment: sorry erkaner how would i go about doing that..every time I've tried putting it all into a single event it breaks the whole thing

Comment: @TryingAtCode can you try step by step? for example can you take out `!$("div[id^='Drop']").hasClass('wrong') &&` part and see what happens?

Comment: hi erkaner i did what you suggested but the code still broke..nothing happened..the dialog boxes wouldn't come up and the video wouldn't play

Comment: @TryingAtCode please see the demo, it is working actually https://jsfiddle.net/erkaner/u4q9435q/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
$('#run').click(function(){
  var drp = $("[id^='Drop']");
  if(drp.hasClass('wrong'))$('#Incorrect').dialog('open');    
  if(drp.is(':empty'))$('#Wrong2').dialog('open');  
  if(drp.find('.wrong:empty').length === drp.find('.wrong').length){
    $('#map1').get(0).play();
  }
});
```

Comment: just tried this piece of code and same problem occurs..all 3 functions stop working. Don't know why this happens

Comment: There's a missing `if(` .

Comment: You probably also want some elses in there to ensure that only one of the actions occurs.`

Comment: Yeah, I'm not saying that what you're trying to do makes any sense, since you're just playing a video if any of them are empty.

Comment: Think it might be fixed now.

Comment: If I'm right, then the last condition is just an `else` after the other two.