# In creating an if/then statement in js, how do I test for data in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

In Chrome console, this is what my array looks like when it has no data:

```
Object {Series1: Array[0]}
```

When it has data, it looks like this:

```
Object {Series1: Array[10]}
```

I tried this out but didn't have any luck:

```
function testfunction() {
    if (array[Series1] !== 'undefined' && array[Series1] !== null) {
        alert("There is data");
    } else {
        alert("No data here");
    }
};

$(document).ready(testfunction);
```

Comment: 1 - You dont have an array, you have an object that contains an array. 2 -  possible duplicate of [How do I check if a (javascript) array value is empty or null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2672380/how-do-i-check-if-a-javascript-array-value-is-empty-or-null).

Comment: Any idea how to test that the object has data based on the above example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Test the length of the array for an empty array:

```
if (array.Series1 && array.Series1.length) {
    //Populated
}
```

Also, unless `Series1` in your sample was a variable, it has to be quoted for bracket notation.

Comment: It is a variable. How do I quote the variable?

Comment: You don't quote the variable, you use bracket notation like you werr

Comment: Ah, gotcha. Tried it and I get this error: "Uncaught ReferenceError: array is not defined"

Comment: Well I assumed `array` was the variable name for your object (since that what your sample used)