# Javascript: if an array has object or is no empty

Tags: javascript, json

I have some JSON data like below:

```
{
  "errorCode": null,
  "message": "Success",
  "result": {

  },
  "totalRecord": 0,
  "checkAccess": true,
  "token": "fb8904acf4dbf0406ac3fd16acd9b84807d2a0e2913aecc3f39e90ca4b53161af6058ca5ee46b9877b75292e5ca9b8df969a325fa3b40c0e4acde546a431f55f6c07de8a854b9e0bf6aeba314d239267"
}
```

In the JSON you can find the `"result"` is empty, but how can I identify it by if statement? I tried to use `!== "undedined"` and `!==null` but the statment still executes.

```
if(trend1_data[0].result !== 'undefined'){
    var resultone = trend1_data[0].result;
    var chartVal1 = resultone.mention30d.chartValues;
    for(var i=0; i < chartVal1.length; i++){
        vol1.push(chartVal1[i].value);//a for loop to generate value array
        Xvol1.push(chartVal1[i].date);// for xaris values e.g:date
    }
}
```

Comment: `Object.keys(..).length` maybe?

Comment: You're checking if `resultone` exists before you're declaring it. Switch lines one and two of that second code block you have.

Comment: i have corrected it and will tried the suggestion above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`result` is an object inside json array

Hope this will be useful

```
var a = [{
"errorCode": null,
  "message": "Success",
  "result": {

  },
  "totalRecord": 0,
  "checkAccess": true,
  "token": "someValue"
} 
]

alert(Object.keys(a[0].result).length)
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/hssk3fss/1/)

Comment: I can't modify the JSON file so i am not able to put var obj in there

Comment: i tried (trend2_data[0].result).length but the outcome is undefined

Comment: Object.keys(trend2_data[0].result).length; seem fine

Answer (score 0):

if the `obj` is

```
var obj = {
  "errorCode": null,
  "message": "Success",
  "result": {

  },
  "totalRecord": 0,
  "checkAccess": true,
  "token": "fb8904acf4dbf0406ac3fd16acd9b84807d2a0e2913aecc3f39e90ca4b53161af6058ca5ee46b9877b75292e5ca9b8df969a325fa3b40c0e4acde546a431f55f6c07de8a854b9e0bf6aeba314d239267"
}
```

try this

```
resultone = obj.result && ( Array.isArray( obj.result ) && obj.result.length ) || Object.keys(obj.result).length;
```

This will check obj.result in following order (second step is optional if you already know that result can only be an object not an array)

1) If `obj.result` exists

2) If yes, then whether it is an array and if it is an array then does it have items in it

3) If it is not an array, then does it have any keys.

resultone will be either true/false now, Now you can use it as

```
if ( resultone )
{
}
```

Comment: I can't modify the JSON file so i am not able to put var obj in there

Comment: @anson920520 thats fine, I have just shown it as an example here.

Answer (score -1):

Your `resultone` is either undefined or you should check differently with `resultone < array.length`

Check [How do I check if a JavaScript array value is empty or null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2672380/how-do-i-check-if-a-javascript-array-value-is-empty-or-null)