# Javascript check if array filled from function

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this function

```
offer.getReceivedItems(function(err, items) {
```

It returns an array (items) or throws an error `err` if it failed.
Many times, when there isn't an `err`, the items array is empty.
Like

```
[]
```

But when this array is empty, I need to try the same function again

```
offer.getReceivedItems(function(err, items) {
```

but how I can go back to it, when items is empty...

I tried so much, but I cannot find it...

Code looks like

```
offer.getReceivedItems(function(err, items) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("Couldn't get received items: " + err);
            offer.decline();
        } else {
            console.log(items);
            items.forEach(function(item,i,arr){
            ....
```

The `forEach` doesn't run when there is an empty array...

Comment: `items.length` will be zero if there is nothing in the array.

Comment: @vlaz that i know. But how i can "restart" that he trying this function again... i can make `if(items.length > 0)` but how i can make that he do offer.getReceivedItems again?

Comment: Make it recursive by calling offer.getReceivedItems again in the else. Or, better yet, use Promises with resolve and reject.

Comment: @ScottMarcus can you show me an example? i am not so good in javascript

Comment: See [multiple, sequential fetch() Promise](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38034574/multiple-sequential-fetch-promise/38034756?s=7|1.0963#38034756) . When should process conclude?

Answer (score 1):

You should check if the array is empty before iterating with `forEach`.  Check `items.length`.

There is a much longer, detailed explanation in [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2672411/2441511).

Comment: I know that with the checking of length, but how i can restart from beginning, if the length is zero?... that is my problem :/

Comment: What function is `offer.getReceivedItems` inside of?  (E.g., if it's called `tryItems`, like so: `function tryItems(args) { offer.getRecievedItems ... }`) You can recursively call that external function inside the `else` of your code snippet, like was suggested by Scott Marcus in a comment above, e.g. `else { if (items.length === 0) { tryItems(args); } ... }`

Comment: that i know... but how i can get back to the start?... @teroi that he trys again

Comment: What do you mean by "back to the start"?

Answer (score 1):

I am having trouble understanding what it is you are trying to do but does the following help you?

```
var callBack = function(err, items) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("Couldn't get received items: " + err);
            offer.decline();
            offer.getReceivedItems(callBack); // Call again
        } else {
            console.log(items);
            items.forEach(function(item,i,arr){
            ....
        }
    };

// Original call
offer.getReceivedItems(callBack);
```