# How can I remove parts of my JSON input for which the value is brackets in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, json

If I have a JSON input like the below:

```
{
  "a": [],
  "b" : "cat",
  "c" : "10001",
  "g" : "",
  "h" : {
      "d": {},
      "m": []
  }   
}
```

How could I write a function that would remove all rows where the value is brackets: {} or [], resulting in:

```
{
  "b" : "cat",
  "c" : "10001",
  "g" : ""
}
```

Comment: "hash" ? What hash. Just iterate and remove items. What's exactly the problem ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/346021/438992

Comment: Sorry, I am just not sure what to use in Javascript to check if a value is brackets.......

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2672411/438992

Comment: Try `for(var i in obj) if(typeof obj[i] == 'object') delete obj[i]`

Comment: @NenadVracar oh I just want it to delete the object if it is empty brackets though, would it delete brackets with values in it as well?

Comment: There is no `h` in desired output.

Comment: @NenadVracar yup because both values inside were empty, so it would end up with empty brackets and consequently get deleted

Comment: @Nerl Could you clarify your last comment, if so then re-check your desired output!

Comment: What if you have property like this `"h" : {"d": {},"m": [{'asdf': [{"c": {}}]}]}  `?

Comment: @NenadVracar Ah, then I'd want the whole thing to get deleted, but if it was "h" : {"d": {"hi"},"m": [{'asdf': [{"c": {}}]}]}, I'd want was "h" : {"d": {"hi"}}

Comment: Check my answer bellow I've updated it! By the way it uses **recursion**!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function clean(obj) {
  for(var key in obj) {
    if(obj[key] instanceof Array && ! obj[key].length) // if it's an array and it's empty
      delete obj[key];                                 // then remove it
    else if(typeof obj[key] === "object") {            // if it's an object
      clean(obj[key]);                                 // clean it
      if(! Object.keys(obj[key]).length)               // and if after cleaning it turned out to be empty
        delete obj[key];                               // then remove it
    }
  }
}

var obj = {
  "a": [],
  "b" : "cat",
  "c" : "10001",
  "d" : [55, 80],
  "g" : "",
  "h" : {
      "d": {},
      "m": []
  },
  "i" : {
      "d": {
        "l": 0
      },
      "m": []
  }   
};

clean(obj);
console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function to iterate through the properties of your object and only grab the values that are not of the type "object".  Note the function also checks `hasOwnProperty` to ensure that it's not an object's prototype property

```
var strippedObject;
for (var property in object) {
    if (object.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
        if(typeof object[property] != "object"){
            strippedObject[property] = object[property];
        }
    }
}
```