# how do i get value to my array from each loop if the inner elements were different

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

I am in the middle of this js from morning everytime i think it is going to be completed i get another block. What i am trying to get is the values from the different elements like some of them are `<input type="text">` and others were `<select>` here is my code

```
var eduarray = [];
    $('.education-groupbox').each(function(index, el) {
        eduarray[index] = [];   
        var s = $(this).attr('id');
        //console.log();
        $('#'+s+' .inputs').each(function(key, value) {

            //console.log($(this).children('.seviyeoptions').val());
            if(key == 1)
            {

                eduarray[index][key].push($(value).children('.seviyeoptions').val());
            }

        });

    });
```

and here is the html part

```
<div id="education-groupbox" class="education-groupbox">
  <div class="inputs col-3">
    <label for="email">Seviye</label>
    <select class="seviyeoptions" name="" id="">
      <option value="option one"></option>
      <option value="option one">Option One</option>
      <option value="option two">Option Two</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="inputs col-3">
    <label for="email">Okul Adı</label>
    <input type="text" name="email" />
  </div>
  <div class="inputs col-3">
    <label for="email">Bölüm</label>
    <input type="text" name="email" />
  </div>
  <div class="inputs col-3">
    <label for="email">Mezuniyet Yılı</label>
    <select class="mezuniyetoptions" name="" id="">
      <option value="option one"></option>
      <option value="option one">Option One</option>
      <option value="option two">Option Two</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to get all the values from the all form elements which are in .inputs class block. please advice.

Comment: "like some of them are and others were here is my code" ? Could you please try to write properly, because understanding your question isn't easy.

Comment: sorry for the confusion some words were removed by stackoverflow as i guess they were code ..let me edit the question again

Comment: Wrap those code words with  ` backticks ` , the key is located top left of keyboard.

Comment: got it and corrected thanks :) please check now if it is understandable

Comment: where is the *key* var definition?

Comment: your selector won't give any data.

Comment: @vlk it's a function parameter

Comment: @vlk i am using key from here `$('#'+s+' .inputs').each(function(key, value) {`  is it wrong ?

Comment: @2by2 yes it always send me undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give your div's ids, your current selector `$('#'+s+' .inputs').each(function(key, value) {`
 won't work as there are no `id` on your div which have class `inputs`.

```js
$('#get').on('click', function () {
        var eduarray = [];
        $('.education-groupbox').each(function (index, el) {
            eduarray[index] = [];
            var s = $(this).attr('id');
            //console.log();
            $('#' + s + ' .inputs').each(function (key, value) {
              if ($(this).find('select').length) {
                  eduarray[index].push($(this).find('select > option:selected').val());
              }
              if ($(this).find('input').length) {
                  eduarray[index].push($(this).find('input').val());
              }
            });

            console.log(eduarray);
        });
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="education-groupbox" class="education-groupbox">
    <div id="select" class="inputs col-3">
        <label for="email">Seviye</label>
        <select class="seviyeoptions" name="" id="">
            <option value="option one"></option>
            <option value="option one">Option One</option>
            <option value="option two">Option Two</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div id="input" class="inputs col-3">
        <label for="email">Okul Adı</label>
        <input type="text" name="email"/>
    </div>
    <div id="input2" class="inputs col-3">
        <label for="email">Bölüm</label>
        <input type="text" name="email"/>
    </div>
    <div id="input3" class="inputs col-3">
        <label for="email">Mezuniyet Yılı</label>
        <select class="mezuniyetoptions" name="" id="">
            <option value="option one"></option>
            <option value="option one">Option One</option>
            <option value="option two">Option Two</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
<button id="get">Get values</button>
```

**UPDATE**

You can also use an object/associative array instead of a standard array, and set the object properties with the value of the name attribute of each element.

```js
$('#get').on('click', function () {
        var eduarray = {};
        $('.education-groupbox').each(function (index, el) {
            var s = $(this).attr('id');
            //console.log();
            $('#' + s + ' .inputs').each(function (key, value) {
              if ($(this).find('select').length) {
                  eduarray[$(this).find('select').attr('name')] = ($(this).find('select > option:selected').val());
              }
              if ($(this).find('input').length) {
                  eduarray[$(this).find('input').attr('name')] = ($(this).find('input').val());
              }
            });

            console.log(eduarray);
        });
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="education-groupbox" class="education-groupbox">
    <div id="select" class="inputs col-3">
        <label for="email">Seviye</label>
        <select class="seviyeoptions" name="seviyeoptions" id="">
            <option value="option one"></option>
            <option value="option one">Option One</option>
            <option value="option two">Option Two</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div id="input" class="inputs col-3">
        <label for="email">Okul Adı</label>
        <input type="text" name="email"/>
    </div>
    <div id="input2" class="inputs col-3">
        <label for="email">Bölüm</label>
        <input type="text" name="email2"/>
    </div>
    <div id="input3" class="inputs col-3">
        <label for="email">Mezuniyet Yılı</label>
        <select class="mezuniyetoptions" name="mezuniyetoptions" id="">
            <option value="option one"></option>
            <option value="option one">Option One</option>
            <option value="option two">Option Two</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
<button id="get">Get values</button>
```

Comment: how do i check if eduarray is empty ?

Comment: check the length of the array `.length` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2672380/how-do-i-check-if-a-javascript-array-value-is-empty-or-null

Comment: `if (eduarray == undefined || eduarray == null || eduarray.length === 0 || (eduarray.length == 1 && eduarray[0] == "")) {

  alert('s');
 }else{
  alert('a');
  console.log(eduarray);
 }`

Comment: doing this to check but it always runs else condition

Comment: this part `eduarray.length == 1 && eduarray[0] == ""` makes it fail

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you know id of available select boxes and input fields in the template

**Sample Code**

```js
$("button").click(function(){

var map={};
var arrayList=[];
map.selectOne=$("#selectOne").val();
map.selectTwo=$("#selectTwo").val();
map.email=$("#email").val();
arrayList.push(map);
console.info(arrayList);
console.log(map);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <label>selectOne</label>
 <select   id="selectOne">
 <option value="option one">Option One</option>
 <option value="option one">Option Two</option>
 <option value="option two">Option Three</option>
 </select>
 <br>
 
  <label>selectTwo</label>
  <select id="selectTwo">
  <option value="option one">Option One</option>
 <option value="option one">Option Two</option>
 <option value="option two">Option Three</option>
  </select> 
   <br>
   <label for="email">Email</label> <input id="email" type="text" name="email" />
 <br>
<button>submit</button>
```