# How to return a specific value when if a value never occurs in an array function?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

Trying to get this code to output -1 when value never occurs in an array.

```
function IndexOf (array,value) {
  var index = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    if (array[i] === value) {
      index.push(i);
      return index.pop();
} else if (value === undefined) {
      return -1;
}
}
```

EDIT: not allowed to use .indexOf for this particular case.

EDIT 2: Sorry I wasn't more clear. I need to return the last matched element as opposed to first.

Comment: why don't you use `.indexOf` which already does that for you ?

Comment: Not allowed to for this specific case

Comment: Because this is a code challenge lol solve it yourself. I believe in you

Comment: I will give you a hint: you don't need the else if block

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I check in JavaScript if a value exists at a certain array index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2672380/how-do-i-check-in-javascript-if-a-value-exists-at-a-certain-array-index)

Comment: About returning the last matched element Instead of first - should be simple enough to adapt @CertainPerformance’s answer below. Why don’t you give it a shot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick to finding the `last occurrence` of an element is to `start` at the `end` (`array.length-1`) and `iterate` back towards the `start` using `i--`.

See [`return`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return) and [`for loop`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) for more info.

```js
// Index Of.
function indexOf(array, value) {
  for (var i = array.length-1; i >= 0; i --) {
    if (array[i] == value) return i
  }
  return -1
}

// Proof.
console.log(indexOf([ 0, 1, 3, 1, 2 ], 1))
console.log(indexOf([ 0, 1, 3, 1, 2 ], 2))
console.log(indexOf([ 0, 1, 3, 1, 2 ], 4))
console.log(indexOf([ 3, 3, 3 ], 3))
console.log(indexOf([], 5))
```

Comment: Sorry I wasn't very clear. I need to return the last occurrence of the value as opposed to first.

Comment: Too easy, see above  @Binny.H

Answer (score 0):

you can use indexOf function of Array object.

```
function checkArray(yourArray, value) {
  if (yourArray.indexOf(value) > -1) {
     // it means the value exists, so it has an index which is greater than -1.
     // action
  } else {
     return -1;
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention. I cannot use .indexOf

Answer (score 0):

You have

```
function IndexOf(array, value) {
  // ...
    } else if (value === undefined) {
      return -1;
```

So when the second argument is ever provided, `-1` will never be returned. There also isn't much point pushing to an array and then immediately `pop`ping it and `return`ing it - just return the `i` itself.

Just wait until all iterations are finished instead, and then return -1.

```js
function IndexOf(array, value) {
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i] === value) return i;
  }
  return -1;
}
console.log(IndexOf([0, 1, 3, 1, 2], 1));
console.log(IndexOf([0, 1, 3, 1, 2], 2));
console.log(IndexOf([0, 1, 3, 1, 2], 3));
console.log(IndexOf([3, 3, 3], 3));
console.log(IndexOf([], 5));
```

Answer (score 0):

The below code works for your purpose, where returning -1 is the only other return option if the value isn't found in the array.

```
function IndexOf (array,value) {
  var index = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    if (array[i] === value) {
      index.push(i);
      return index.pop();
    }
  return -1
}
```

In your code, value will never equal undefined, rather value isn't located in the array and undefined is being returned due to lack of a return statement handling that condition.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. I hope this will work

```
function IndexOf(array, value) {
        var index = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {

            if (array[i] === value) {
                index.push(i);
            }
        }
        if(index.length > 0){
            return index.length;
        } else{
            return -1;
        }
    }
    console.log(IndexOf([0, 1, 3, 1, 2], 1));
    console.log(IndexOf([0, 1, 3, 1, 2], 2));
    console.log(IndexOf([0, 1, 3, 1, 2], 3));
    console.log(IndexOf([3, 3, 3], 3));
    console.log(IndexOf([], 5));
```

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this snippet will be useful

```js
function IndexOf(array, value) {
  // creating an empty array 
  var index = []; 
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    // if value matches return the index of the first matched element
    if (array[i] === value) {
      return i;
    } 
      return -1
    
}
console.log(IndexOf([0, 1, 3, 1, 2], 1));
console.log(IndexOf([0, 1, 3, 1, 2], 2));
console.log(IndexOf([0, 1, 3, 1, 2], 3));
console.log(IndexOf([3, 3, 3], 3));
console.log(IndexOf([], 5));
```

Comment: Sorry I wasn't more clear. I need to return the last matched element as opposed to first.
So output should be as followed:

    console.log(IndexOf([0, 1, 3, 1, 2], 1)); 3
    console.log(IndexOf([0, 1, 3, 1, 2], 2)); 4
    console.log(IndexOf([0, 1, 3, 1, 2], 3)); -1
    console.log(IndexOf([3, 3, 3], 3)); 2
    console.log(IndexOf([], 5)); -1

Answer (score 0):

```
    function IndexOf(array, value) {
      var match = -1;

      for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
        if (array[i] === value)
          match = i;

      return match;
    }

console.log(IndexOf([3, 3, 3], 3)); // will return 2 as the last match index is 2
console.log(IndexOf([1,2,4], 5)); // will return -1 as there is no match
```

I guess this is what you are looking for.