# How to apply conditions based on array index?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

lets assume i have data now i want to check if index is there and process the logic based on that condition, what would be correct approach using ES6 to run below conditions ?

Any better way to achieve this task ?

main.ts

```
data = [
  {"obj1":"data"},
  {"obj2": "data"},

  ]

if(data[0].length) {
    // process logic 
}

if(data[1].length) {
    // process logic 
}
```

Comment: How about _looping_?

Comment: If its the same logic you can just use a foreach loop... or for of loop (or simple for/while loop)

Comment: Is this different logic in each case or should you do the same thing for each value that matches? Also, are you checking if the object has a `length` property or is that something else?

Comment: @undefined can anyone provide example how i would do that

Comment: What...write a basic loop?

Comment: @vlaz just want to check if response `data[0]` has object there then do the rest of the logic

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I check in JavaScript if a value exists at a certain array index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2672380/how-do-i-check-in-javascript-if-a-value-exists-at-a-certain-array-index)

Answer (score 0):

not really sure what exactly you want to do, but i think map/forEach work...

```
data = [
  {"obj1":"data"},
  {"obj2": "data"},

]
data.map((el, i) => { return i%2 == 0? Object.keys(el) : null })
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to check if the **data** array contains valid `object` type values and has some key->value pair in it. If so, do it in this way

```
for(let value of data){
  // may ignore few checks if required
  if(value && typeof(value) === 'object' && Object.keys(value).length){
    // value is valid and is object type with some value
    // write your logic here
  }
}
```