# Element has no method hasAttribute, Why?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to iterate "up" through the DOM nodes from a given element to get the first parent element which has the attribute 'animated'.

```
var el = evt.target;
    console.log(el);
while (!el.hasAttribute('animated'))
   { el = el.parentNode; }
return el;
    console.log(el);
```

Throws error:

`>>>Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLDocument> has no method 'hasAttribute'`

How is this possible? I've clearly declared the variable `el` and the first log is correct .

Comment: Why are you doing `console.log(el)` AFTER you do `return el;`?  The `console.log(el)` will never be executed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `document` object:

- Is a node
- Is the `parentNode` of the root element (if you were using HTML that would be the `<html>` element)
- Is not an element.

Only elements have attributes, so only element objects have a `hasAttribute` method.

You need to stop testing when you reach the document object (or when you aren't testing an element any longer).

```
while (
    el.nodeType === 1 && 
    (!el.hasAttribute('animated'))
) {
```

Comment: Can we also use `hasOwnProperty`? [More details over here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/135448/how-do-i-check-to-see-if-an-object-has-an-attribute-in-javascript).

Comment: I've no idea if the DOMs for arbitrary markup documents map attributes directly onto properties or not.

Comment: I would check `el.nodeType == 1` (which is guaranteed to work) instead of `el.hasAttribute` (which is not).

Comment: It fixed a strange behaviour on my (probably inefficient, since I classify myself as an noob) script. `getAttribute` returned a error on the second time which I was using it, but the first did work. I performed the `nodeType === 1` check and now it executes beautifully. +1

Answer (score 1):

`var el = evt.target`
 is a `document` object and therefore does not have a `hasAttribute` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

You could also make it into a function that returns either `null` or the ancestor node that has that attribute:

```
function findNodeWithAttribute(el, attr) {
    while (true) {
        if (!el || !el.hasAttribute) {
            return null;
        } else if (el.hasAttribute(attr)) {
            return el;
        }
        el = el.parentNode;
    }
}
```