# How to check whether a Javascript object has a value for a given key?

Tags: javascript, dictionary, key

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I check to see if an object has an attribute in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/135448/how-do-i-check-to-see-if-an-object-has-an-attribute-in-javascript)

I have a Javascript object defined as following:

```
var mmap = new Object();

mmap['Q'] = 1;
mmap['Z'] = 0;
mmap['L'] = 7;
...
```

How to check whether this map has a value for a given key (for example 'X')? Does `.hasOwnProperty()` get into play?

Comment: Why not `hasOwnProperty`? (Excepting aesthetic reasons.) The difference between that an `in` is that `in` will traverse the [[prototype]] as well.

Comment: `mmap.has(key)` is latest ECMAScript 6 way of checking the existance of a key in a map. [Refer to this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/has) for complete details.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

```
if ('X' in mmap)
{
    // ...
}
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/38Xpz/) is an example on JSFiddle.

`hasOwnProperty` is also valid, but using `in` is much more painless. The only difference is that `in` returns prototype properties, whereas `hasOwnProperty` does not.

Answer (score 10):

You can use:

```
(mmap['X'] === undefined)
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eDTrY/

Comment: However, if the property was set to undefined, it still exists, but this will return false.

Comment: `{x: undefined}.x === undefined` is true

Comment: Valid point, not to mention if some idiot redefines *undefined*