# Why in the iteration a prototype function appears?

Tags: javascript, prototype

So there is this function

```
Array.prototype.containsCaseInsensitive = function(obj) {
  var i = this.length;
  while (i--) {
    if (this[i].toUpperCase() === obj.toUpperCase()) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

then I create this array:

```
ary = [0,1,2,3];
for (item in ary){
  console.log(ary[item])
}
```

The output is as follows:

```
0
1
2
3
function(obj) {
    var i = this.length;
    while (i--) {
       if (this[i].toUpperCase() === obj.toUpperCase()) {
           return true;
       }
    }
    return false;
 }
```

Why is the function in the iteration?
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your property is enumerable (although you shouldn't enumerate the keys of an array using `for ... in ...` anyway).

On ES5 compatible browsers you can safely add that function as a non-enumerable property using [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty):

```
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'containsCaseInsensitive', {
    value: function() {
        ...
    }
});
```

Comment: The only problem is that version is 1.8.5 so decrease browser compatibility. In some cases, I think is still better filter the elements.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `for .. in` the array is treated as an object and that is why it will show you all the properties. Use regular for to achieve the effect you want.

Answer (score 0):

Because `containsCaseInsensitive` is a member of your array, and you're iterating over all members of the array. You should not write `for ... in` iterations to iterate over the items in an array.

Answer (score 0):

Because `for..in` outputs all the enumerable properties of an object.

If you want only the values of the array, you can use:

```
for (item in ary){
   if ( ary.hasOwnProperty( item ) )
      console.log(ary[item])
}
```

In supported environments, you can also use `defineProperty` to set the function as non-enumerable, like this:

```
Object.defineProperty( Array.prototype, 'containsCaseSensitive', {
    value: function( obj ) {},
    enumerable: false
    // ^ this is default when you use defineProperty, so you don't need it
    // but it is to show you how that works :-)
} );
```

However, it is usually not recommended to use `for..in` for arrays, you only use it for literal objects.

For arrays, it is recommended to use:

```
for ( var i = 0, l = arr.length; i < l; i++ ) {
    console.log( arr[ i ] );
}
```

Or, if supported:

```
arr.forEach( function( el ) {
    console.log( el );
} );
```

Comment: I think the "if supported" clause makes `.forEach` and even worse practice than `for ... in`, when it comes to JavaScript. The `hasOwnProperty` check works for the specific example because the property is defined at the Array object's, but it does not address issues such as `var x = [1,2]; x.prop = 'a';`

Comment: Why do you think it makes it even worse practice? If you only support modern browsers, you should definitely use `forEach`, it's great and does all things. In node.js, I'd bite you if you didn't use it.

Comment: @DavidHedlund I disagree.  `.forEach` is now _expected_ practice, and you should use a shim to add it for browsers that don't support it natively.  In properly written ES5 code `.hasOwnProperty` is almost never needed.

Answer (score 0):

You are iterating over all properties of the object. You need to look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/135448/how-do-i-check-to-see-if-an-object-has-an-attribute-in-javascript).