# Change colour from bool within array in QML

Tags: javascript, arrays, boolean, qml, v-play

I am looking to change the colour of a Calendar cell from a Boolean within an array (`calendarListModel`).

Here's a sample of the array:

```
[
{"date":1544443200000,"name":"Edward","status":1},
{"date":1544529600000,"name":"Katie","status":0},
{"date":1544616000000,"name":"Claire","status":1}
]
```

**What I want to do is change the colour of my calendar marker depending on the Boolean value within `calendarListModel` (`"status": 0 or 1`)**.

The code for my marker is;

```
Rectangle {
    id: calendarMarker
    visible: arrayFromFireBase.indexOf(styleData.date.getTime()) > -1
    anchors.fill: parent
    color:  "blue"
}
```

I have tried making changes to the colour of the Rectangle with things such as `calendarListModel.status ? "blue" : "red"` amongst other variations but am either getting each cell as blue or red, or none at all?

**Question: What would be the best way to change the colour based on a true/false value from the array?**

I am using `Calendar` from the `QtQuick.Controls` to display dates and `CalendarStyle` from `QtQuick.Controls.Styles` to assign a custom style. I'm also using the V-Play sdk.

Here's a minimal, complete, and verifiable example of what I'm currently doing:

```
import VPlayApps 1.0
import QtQuick 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.1

App {
    id: app

    //  this model is read from a firebase db using v-play
    property var calendarListModel: [
        {"date":1544443200000,"name":"Edward","status":1},
        {"date":1544529600000,"name":"Katie","status":0},
        {"date":1547182800000,"name":"Claire","status":1}
    ]

    Calendar {
        id: calendar
        anchors.fill: parent
        selectedDate: new Date()
        weekNumbersVisible: true
        focus: true
        onSelectedDateChanged: {
            const day = selectedDate.getDate();
            const month = selectedDate.getMonth() + 1;
            const year = selectedDate.getFullYear();
        }

       style: CalendarStyle {
           dayOfWeekDelegate: Item {
               width: parent.width
               height: dp(30)
               Rectangle {
                   anchors.fill: parent
                   border.color: "#00000000"
                   Label {
                       id: dayOfWeekDelegateText
                       text: Qt.locale().dayName(styleData.dayOfWeek, Locale.ShortFormat)
                       anchors.centerIn: parent
                       color: "black"
                   }
               }
           }

           //  a delegate for each day cell
           dayDelegate: Item {
               id: container

               readonly property color sameMonthDateTextColor: "#444"
               readonly property color selectedDateColor: "#20d5f0"
               readonly property color selectedDateTextColor: "white"
               readonly property color differentMonthDateTextColor: "#bbb"

               //  the background of each cell
               Rectangle {
                   anchors.fill: parent
                   border.color: "#00000000"
                   color: styleData.selected ? selectedDateColor : "white"
               }

               //  a marker on the upper-left corner on each cell
               Rectangle {
                   id: calendarMarker
                   property bool isConfirmed: false
                   anchors {
                       top: parent.top; left: parent.left
                   }

                   width: 12
                   height: width

                   //  the issue lies here
                   color: {
                        var confCol
                        calendarListModel.indexOf(status? true : false)
                        confCol ? "#4286f4" : "red"
                   }

               }

               // the day number
               Label {
                   id: dayDelegateText
                   text: styleData.date.getDate()
                   anchors.centerIn: parent
                   color:  styleData.selected ? selectedDateTextColor : styleData.visibleMonth ? sameMonthDateTextColor : differentMonthDateTextColor
               }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you post a minimal, viable, example?  i.e. something we can paste into QtCreate and try it out for you.  Perhaps a standalone QML file?

Comment: My psychic powers suggest calendarListModel or calendarListModel.status is undefined.  Does QtCreator show any output in the debug window when you run your code under debug?

Comment: Could you post the part where you "build" the calendar in QML? I'm guessing you have a repeater or something and you need to use `model` or `modelData` instead of `calendarListModel`

Comment: @selbie Apologies! I try to keep myself as clear as possible and think I am but I guess not haha! I've updated the question with code from the `main.qml` and `calendar.qml` for you to see! I want the `calendarMarker` in the calendar.qml to change colour depending on the bool of the status read from firebase of each date! let me know if that makes more sense?

Comment: @Amfasis again sorry for making it confusing, as with my above comment to selbie I've updated the question, hopefully it makes more sense now if not let me know and i'll edit further! Thanks again for the comments people!

Comment: @Ldweller Hi there, thanks for putting your code up there. Right now, I'm getting errors like "AppButton is not a type". Please help make this a [mcve] by including the import statements as well. (Make sure the code that you post in your question is working by itself and fully reproduces your problem). Btw, is this v-play you're using?

Comment: Yes @TrebuchetMS it is vplay would that be causing it not allowing `AppButton` sorry? I am happy to throw the full code into paste bin for you to take a look at?

Comment: @Ldweller I can't reproduce your code as I'm getting several errors: `ReferenceError: dp is not defined
file:GamePlayground//qml/Main.qml:35: ReferenceError: dayCycleArr is not defined
file:GamePlayground//qml/Main.qml:154: ReferenceError: calendarListModel is not defined` (and many more...) from the VPlay Live Client. Others and I do not wish for the "full code". If possible, please **minimise** your code, ensuring that it's still **complete** and **verifiable** so that we can reproduce it. ([read more](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)...) Thanks.

Comment: @TrebuchetMS Hey! Thanks again for taking the time to look at this, I've updated the answer (thanks for the edits) with running code, I know there are some parts which are still code heavy but I feel with all the back and fourth between firebase It needs to be kept in there for you to connect up properly when testing! let me know, thanks a million again!

Comment: Hi again, I don't think the issue's coming from firebase. If possible, try removing those components and replacing your array/list properties with sample data (also I didn't want to bother with generating a plugin license). And ok, your issue's with `RealtimeCalendar:calendarMarker`, yes? What do you intend `calendarListModel.indexOf(status? true : false)` to do? Also is `calendarListModel` similar to `calendarListView` from your question? (I have no idea since I can't run the firebase plugin, that's why I've been trying to get you to remove the fb components.)

Comment: @TrebuchetMS oh my god sorry yes `calendarListView` in my original question should be `calendarListModel` huge critical typo from me! The issue is with calendarMarker you are correct, i want it to be one of two colours depending on each dates true/false status in the `calendarListModel` indexOf ect is one of the variations i have tried to get this working with either a red mark for false confirmed and a blue mark for true confirmed status!

Comment: I think you've got several dupes here: [Find object by id in an array of js objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364150/find-object-by-id-in-an-array-of-javascript-objects). [How to find the index of an object by key and value in a js array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11258077/how-to-find-index-of-an-object-by-key-and-value-in-an-javascript-array).

Comment: @Ldweller I've polished your question up a bit. Please check over to make sure that my edits were accurate. At the same time, please understand how I replaced your code with an mcve, the redundancy removed and the simplicity gained in solving the problem. Hopefully I didn't misunderstand your question. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright, right now you're using an array of objects and trying to index it directly, which is no good. (Especially since you're currently indexing for `true`/`false` values, which doesn't comprise individual elements in `calendarListModel`.) Even if you could reconstruct the object with a date, name, and status, they'll still be different objects.

Use [`Array.prototype.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) instead.

```
color: {
    var modelObject = calendarListModel.find(
       function(obj) {
            //  look for a matching date
           return obj.date === styleData.date.getTime();
       }
    );

    if (modelObject === undefined)  //  not found in list model
       return "lightgrey";

    return modelObject.status ? "blue" : "red";
}
```

Here's a before and after tested from a macOS:

Before: Notice how all markers are red. Only the dates specified in `calendarListModel` should have colour to them.
[image: Before]

After: Notice that only the marker at January 11 has colour (blue). Indeed, this is because the date was included in `calendarListModel`: 1544616000000.
[image: After]

Comment: firstly can I say a huge thanks for your patience! It works as intended! Confirmed/unconfirmed showing different colours! I always try to make my questions minimal, complete and verifiable as i can but being a hobbyist things may not read as clearly as intended, but thanks, thanks a million! (P.S I'll use your edited question as reference in the future for sure)