# Querying a JavaScript object

Tags: javascript, object

Given the following three objects, what is an efficient way to return the first object that contains a key-value pair?

```
var obj = {
  item1: {
    name: 'apple',
    color: 'red'
  },
  item2: {
    name: 'blueberry',
    color: 'blue'
  },
  item3: {
    name: 'cherry',
    color: 'red'
  }
};

var obj2 = {
  collection: [
    {
      item1: {
        name: 'apple',
        color: 'red'
      },
      item2: {
        name: 'blueberry',
        color: 'blue'
      },
      item3: {
        name: 'cherry',
        color: 'red'
      }
    }
  ]
};

var obj3 = {
  items: [
    {
      item1: {
        name: 'apple',
        color: 'red'
      }
    },
    {
      item2: {
        name: 'blueberry',
        color: 'blue'
      },
    },
    {
      item3: {
        name: 'cherry',
        color: 'red'
      }
    }
  ]
};
```

I would like to get the same results for the following three statements:

```
getObject(obj, 'color', 'red');
getObject(obj2, 'color', 'red');
getObject(obj3, 'color', 'red');
```

Output:

```
{
  name: 'apple',
  color: 'red'
}
```

Here's what I have so far, but I think it's missing a closure somewhere since it breaks when the function calls itself:

```
function getObject(arg, key, val) {
  if (typeof arg!=='object') return null;
  switch (Object.prototype.toString.call(arg)) {
    case '[object Array]':
      for (var i=0; i<arg.length; ++i) {
        getObject(arg[i], key, val);
      }
      break;
    case '[object Object]':
      for (var i in arg) {
        if (arg.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
          if (typeof arg[i]==='object') {
            getObject(arg[i], key, val);
          } else {
            if (i===key && arg[i]===val) {
              return arg;
            }
          }
        }
      }
      break;
  }
}
```

Comment: FYI, you can use [`Array.isArray()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray) to check if the object is an array.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find index of an object by key and value in an javascript array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11258077/how-to-find-index-of-an-object-by-key-and-value-in-an-javascript-array)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use this function, which will also search in more deeply nested data structures.

```js
function getObject(obj, prop, value) {
    if (Object(obj) !== obj) return; // It is not an object
    if (obj[prop] === value) return obj; // Found it
    for (var key in obj) {
        var result = getObject(obj[key], prop, value);
        if (result) return result; // Found it
    }
}

var obj = {item1: {name: 'apple',color: 'red'},item2: {name: 'blueberry',color: 'blue'},item3: {name: 'cherry',color: 'red'}};
var obj2 = {collection: [{item1: {name: 'apple',color: 'red'},item2: {name: 'blueberry',color: 'blue'},item3: {name: 'cherry',color: 'red'}}]};
var obj3 = {items: [{item1: {name: 'apple',color: 'red'}},{item2: {name: 'blueberry',color: 'blue'},},{item3: {name: 'cherry',color: 'red'}}]};

console.log(getObject(obj, 'color', 'red'));
console.log(getObject(obj2, 'color', 'red'));
console.log(getObject(obj3, 'color', 'red'));
```

Comment: I actually like your answer the most and ended up using it, but unfortunately I accepted another answer before seeing your solution. Apologies.

Comment: I guess better late than never. I found out you could actually unselect an accepted answer. Thanks again for this awesomely concise solution!

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) for a short cut, if the object is found.

```js
function getObject(object, key, value) {
    var result;
    if (!object || typeof object !== 'object') return;
    if (object[key] === value) return object;
    Object.values(object).some(v => result = getObject(v, key, value));
    return result;
}

var obj = { item1: { name: 'apple', color: 'red' }, item2: { name: 'blueberry', color: 'blue' }, item3: { name: 'cherry', color: 'red' } },
    obj2 = { collection: [{ item1: { name: 'apple', color: 'red' }, item2: { name: 'blueberry', color: 'blue' }, item3: { name: 'cherry', color: 'red' } }] },
    obj3 = { items: [{ item1: { name: 'apple', color: 'red' } }, { item2: { name: 'blueberry', color: 'blue' } }, { item3: { name: 'cherry', color: 'red' } }] };

console.log(getObject(obj, 'color', 'red'));
console.log(getObject(obj2, 'color', 'red'));
console.log(getObject(obj3, 'color', 'red'));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your approach within `getObject` is OK, however, as a general approach, you should transform the array for each all.  You can use the function `map` in order to prepare the array for the finding process.

The function `find` "finds" the object according to a specific predicate.

*This is assuming the indexes are related to the keys `->` index `i==0` `->` `items1`, and so on.*

```js
var obj = {item1: {name: 'apple',color: 'red'},item2: {name: 'blueberry',color: 'blue'},item3: {name: 'cherry',color: 'red'}};
var obj2 = {collection: [{item1: {name: 'apple',color: 'red'},item2: {name: 'blueberry',color: 'blue'},item3: {name: 'cherry',color: 'red'}}]};
var obj3 = {items: [{item1: {name: 'apple',color: 'red'}},{item2: {name: 'blueberry',color: 'blue'},},{item3: {name: 'cherry',color: 'red'}}]};

let getObject = (o, key, value) => o.find(obj => obj[key] === value);

console.log(getObject(Object.values(obj), 'color', 'red'));
console.log(getObject(obj2.collection.map((o, i) => o[`item${i+1}`]), 'color', 'red'));
console.log(getObject(obj3.items.map((o, i) => o[`item${i+1}`]), 'color', 'red'));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%; }
```

Comment: Thanks for this, @Ele. While I admire the brevity of the solution, I won't be able to use this right now because (1) the code base is standarized on ES5, and (2) other developers who use this helper function will not know to `.map()` when appropriate.

Comment: @thdoan no problem!

Comment: @thdoan, I just stumbled over this comment: *code base is standardized on ES5*. If ES5 is a requirement, then that should be clearly mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can call the function recursively to reach an object that hasn't any objects-members and filter it by key and value:

```js
function getObject(obj, k, v) {
    for (var key in obj) {
        if (typeof obj[key] === 'object') {
            return getObject(obj[key], k, v);
        } else if (key === k && obj[key] === v) {
            return(obj);
        }
    }   
}

var obj = {
  item1: {
    name: 'apple',
    color: 'red'
  },
  item2: {
    name: 'blueberry',
    color: 'blue'
  },
  item3: {
    name: 'cherry',
    color: 'red'
  }
};

var obj2 = {
  collection: [
    {
      item1: {
        name: 'apple',
        color: 'red'
      },
      item2: {
        name: 'blueberry',
        color: 'blue'
      },
      item3: {
        name: 'cherry',
        color: 'red'
      }
    }
  ]
};

var obj3 = {
  items: [
    {
      item1: {
        name: 'apple',
        color: 'red'
      }
    },
    {
      item2: {
        name: 'blueberry',
        color: 'blue'
      },
    },
    {
      item3: {
        name: 'cherry',
        color: 'red'
      }
    }
  ]
};
console.log(getObject(obj, 'color', 'red'));
console.log(getObject(obj2, 'color', 'red'));
console.log(getObject(obj3, 'color', 'red'));
```