# for..in and hasOwnProperty

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:** 
> [How do I check if an object has a specific property in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/135448/how-do-i-check-if-an-object-has-a-specific-property-in-javascript)

I found the following snippet in Twitter's JavaScript files. Why do they need to call the `hasOwnProperty` function to see `dict` has the `key` property? The *for* loop is running for each 'key' in 'dict' which means 'dict' has 'key'. Am I missing a point?

```
function forEach(dict, f) {
    for (key in dict) {
        if (dict.hasOwnProperty(key))
            f(key, dict[key]);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's well-explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/136411/27512

Comment: Seems like `key` is global where is this code from, can you post a link to it?

Comment: @elclanrs I was wrong. This code is from Chrome's utils.js

Comment: @elclanrs it is more probable that he just don't know that his code is creating this global, it is very easy to forget the `var` in for in loops, **edit**: oh, I just read that it is not his code... interesting

Comment: He must've written it and forgot about it. It's improbable that google code misses the brackets and forgets `var`.

Comment: I would suggest naming such function `forIn` to avoid confusion with `Array.forEach`. It may be good idea to define it on `Object.prototype` via `Object.defineProperty` if you don't care about IE 8, and allow it to accept iterating function of `(key, value)` signature. This would allow for more expressive code, especially in `es6`

Comment: You need to swap the order of arguments in call to `f`, i.e.  `f(dict[key], key)`

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Because if you don't, it will loop through every property on the prototype chain, including ones that you don't know about (that were possibly added by somebody messing with native object prototypes).

This way you're guaranteed only the keys that are on that object instance itself.

Comment: I just don't understand how a so popular and rapidly evolving language like JS after so many years and standards still doesn't a proper loop for object iteration where you don't have to call `hasOwnProperty()` on every single loop step.

Comment: @ScepticalJule `for..in` is specifically to get enumerable properties including inherited ones. If you want only *enumerable own* properties, you can use for `for (const key of Object.keys(obj))`. [Enumerability and ownership of properties table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Enumerability_and_ownership_of_properties#detection_table)

Answer (score 36):

The **[hasOwnProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty)** method lets you know if a property is directly on an instance of an object or inherited from its prototype chain.

Consider the following

```
function ObjWithProto() {
    this.foo = 'foo_val';
}

ObjWithProto.prototype = {bar: 'bar_val'};

var dict = new ObjWithProto();
dict.foobar = 'foobar_val';
```

I.e., you have an *Object* `dict` with properties `foo` and `foobar` that also inherits a property `bar` from its prototype chain.

Now run it through (a modified version of) your code:

```
function forEach(dict) {
    var key;
    for (key in dict) {
        if (dict.hasOwnProperty(key)) 
            console.log('has', key, dict[key]);
        else 
            console.log('not', key, dict[key]);
    }
}
forEach(dict);
```

You will see

```
has foo foo_val
has foobar foobar_val
not bar bar_val
```

This lets you separate properties that an object has itself and those it has inherited (which are usually methods that aren't relevant to the loop).

Furthermore, if you now do `dict.bar = 'new_bar_val';`, the last result will change to `has bar new_bar_val`, letting you distinguish even between properties of the same name as those inherited.

Answer (score 5):

Every object in JavaScript is a dictionary. This means that "toString" and every other method is a key of every Object:

```
var myObj = {};
console.log(myObj["toString"]);
```

But this function is inherited from Object class, so hasOwnProperty tells you if this key is owned by the dictionary or if it is inherited.

```
"toString" in myObj; // true
myObj.hasOwnProperty("toString") // false
```

Answer (score 1):

[blockhead is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12735778/for-in-and-hasownproperty/12735807#12735807) right here. For example, the Prototype.js framework used to extend native arrays with extra helper methods (I do not know the situation with current versions of a framework).

Thus straight usage of "for (key in dict)" would return all the elements of the div plus references to helper methods. Which is kind of unexpected :)

Comment: prototype.js did a lot of things wrong.