# This key / list check is redundant, isn't it?

Tags: javascript

so, I am checking for a key in a list (hash), and I must of coded it two different ways but forget to remove a bit of it. lol. But to me, looking at it - it appears redundant. Is this the case?

```
 var somelist = {
      a : 'somevalue1',
      b : 'somevalue1',
      c : 'somevalue1',
      d : 'somevalue1',
      e : 'somevalue1',
      f : 'somevalue1'
 }

 for(var key in somelist ){
     if(somelist.hasOwnProperty(key)){  // <-- redundant
         // do something
     }
 }
```

if we are looping thru the keys - then the assumption is, it's a property of the list, yes? I want to make sure my brain isn't fried. :-)

**I looked over these two posts:**

[for..in and hasOwnProperty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12735778/for-in-and-hasownproperty)

[How do I check if an object has a property in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/135448/how-do-i-check-to-see-if-an-object-has-a-property-in-javascript/136411#136411)

But my usage seems much more benign. Since I am declaring var key here, isn't it local and I don't have to worry about prototypical chain collisions?

So, it appears that in my usage - it IS redundant or not needed -- but would this be considered 'poor form'. It seems because I do not have this hash sitting in a constructor I don't have to worry about prototypical inheritance etc...

so, my two questions are:

Since I am declaring var key here, isn't it local and I don't have to worry about prototypical chain collisions?

would my usage here be considered 'poor form' even though it isn't needed? I wanted to keep with certain coding standards - but perhaps my intent is wrong here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not about the `key` where you have to worry. It's the object itself.

```
Object.prototype[1] = 1;

var somelist = {}

for (var key in somelist) {
    alert(key);
}

// '1' was alerted
```

Comment: thanks. let me review what you typed, and wrap my brain around it.

Answer (score 1):

You just make your code more robust doing that check, and it is recommended as a best practice. However, to keep intendation shallow, I usually do an inverted pattern:

```
for( var key in obj ) {
    if( !obj.hasOwnProperty( key ) ) {
        continue;
    }

    // do something
}
```

Jo So pointed out a potential conflict, but also your data might just change and then your code can break. A golden rule in software development: Expect failure.