# How to parse JSON to Object which has a property

Tags: c#, json, vb.net, json.net

I need the data back from the server will be with "data" property, and what `JsonConvert.SerializeObject()` return is without. How can I convert it?

From:

```
{
    "name": "Tiger Nixon",
    "position": "System Architect",
    "salary": "$320,800",
    "start_date": "2011/04/25",
    "office": "Edinburgh",
    "extn": "5421"
}
```

To:

```
{
    "data": [{
        "name": "Tiger Nixon",
        "position": "System Architect",
        "salary": "$320,800",
        "start_date": "2011/04/25",
        "office": "Edinburgh",
        "extn": "5421"
    }]
}
```

In VB.net (can be in C# too and I will convert).

Comment: Simply put your object in array before `JsonConvert.SerializeObject()`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26795643/how-to-convert-object-containing-objects-into-array-of-objects This might help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're starting with an instance of your model class, you can just wrap it in an anonymous object and serialize that:

```
Dim anon = New With {.data = New List(Of Model) From {model}}
Dim json As String = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(anon, Formatting.Indented)
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/45RtrC

---

If you're starting with a JSON string, you can transform it using a [`JObject`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm):

```
Dim jo As JObject = JObject.Parse(json)
jo = New JObject(New JProperty("data", New JArray(jo)))
json = jo.ToString()
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/ezP6QR

Answer (score 1):

You can parse it to an array and then serialize that back like

```
Model[] data = JObject.Parse(json_string).ToObject<Model[]>();
```

Considering you have a model associated to your JSON string

```
public class Model
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string position { get; set; }
    public string salary { get; set; }
    public string start_date { get; set; }
    public string office { get; set; }
    public string extn { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: still not get the "name" propery. now its looks like this: [{"status":2,"transactionId":12345,"creditCardNumber":"1234324324","supplier":"Office Depot","createdAt":"2008-12-28T00:00:00","amount":500.0}]