# sorting an object of an object in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, sorting

I've an object as

```
const posts = {
"BAhvZrRwcfu":{

    "text":"Totally need to try this.",
    "user": "heavymetaladam",
  vote: 2

},
"BAcyDyQwcXX":{

    "text":"Wes. WE should have lunch.",
    "user": "jdaveknox",
  vote : 3

 }
};
```

is there a way I can sort based on the vote.It seems easier if i make it an array of object

Comment: Yes, there are possible approaches which can be tried. Can you include the code that you have tried to resolve inquiry at Question? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: it is not only easier, but it is sortable.

Comment: @linux See my answer below. You used keys. You wanted values.

Comment: `var keys = Object.keys(state.posts);

      keys.sort((a, b) => {
        if (a.voteScore < b.voteScore) {
          return -1;
        }
        if (a.voteScore > b.voteScore) {
          return 1;
        }
        // a.voteScore must be equal to b.voteScore
        return 0;
      }).reduce((a, v) => {
       
        return state.posts[v]
      }, {})`

Comment: `"voteScore"` does not appear as a property of an object at code at Question. Can you include the code that you tried at text of Question? Note, there are mismatched quotation marks at `'BAcyDyQwcXX"`

Comment: The object at OP is not valid at `"BAhvZrRwcfu":{{`, do you mean `{"BAhvZrRwcfu":{"text":"Totally need to try this.","user":"heavymetaladam","vote":2},"BAcyDyQwcXX":{"text":"Wes. WE should have lunch.","user":"jdaveknox","vote":3}}`?

Comment: yes,I've corrected the question

Comment: `It seems easier if i make it an array of object` - yes, you are right on this point, because Objects are not "sortable", arrays are

Answer (score 0):

I recommend converting to an array of objects. Then you can control your sorting criteria and change them more easily in the future should those criteria change.

You can do something like this:

`var postsList = Object.values(posts)`

See this Stackoverflow answers for more details on how/why that works:

- [How to convert object containing Objects into array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26795643/how-to-convert-object-containing-objects-into-array-of-objects)

See previous answer on stack overflow for details on sorting an array of objects, if you don't already know how to do this:

- [Sorting an array of JavaScript objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979256/sorting-an-array-of-javascript-objects)

For example, to sort by number of votes:

`posts.sort(function(a, b) {
    return parseInt(a.vote) - parseFloat(b.vote);
});`

Comment: Don't use `parseInt` on numbers!

Comment: I finally found a way , I converted to an array of object first then i sorted it,then i converted back to an object of object

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array of objects from the original object using `Object.entries()`

```js
const posts = {
  "BAhvZrRwcfu": {
    "text": "Totally need to try this.",
    "user": "heavymetaladam",
    "vote": 3
  },
  "BAcyDyQwcXX": {
    "text": "Wes. WE should have lunch.",
    "user": "jdaveknox",
    "vote": 2
  }
};

const sortedPosts = Object.entries(posts)
                    .sort(([, {vote: a}], [, {vote: b}]) => a < b ? -1 : 1)
                    .map(([key, prop]) => ({[key]: prop}));

console.log(sortedPosts);
```

Alternatively you can set the objects within a `Map`

```js
const posts = {
  "BAhvZrRwcfu": {
    "text": "Totally need to try this.",
    "user": "heavymetaladam",
    "vote": 3
  },
  "BAcyDyQwcXX": {
    "text": "Wes. WE should have lunch.",
    "user": "jdaveknox",
    "vote": 2
  }
};

const sortedPosts = new Map;

Object.entries(posts)
.sort(([, {vote: a}], [, {vote: b}]) => a < b ? -1 : 1)
.forEach(([key, prop]) => sortedPosts.set(key, prop));

console.log(sortedPosts);
```

Comment: this works but it returns an array of object,i need an object of an object.I did this to convert back to an object of an object                                        `posts = {}
      for (let num in aa) {
        posts[aa[num].id] = aa[num]
      }`

Answer (score 0):

Objects are intrinsically key-based and not ordered. To access it in a certain order, I find it helpful to create an order list:

```
var order = [];
$.each(posts, function(key, value) {
  order.push([key, value.vote])
});  //use for loop if you prefer
order.sort(function(a,b){
  return a[1] - b[1];  //ascending order
})
```

Then you can access `posts` based on the order of the array `order`, e.g.

```
order.forEach(function(e){
  posts[e[0]];
})
```