# How to convert object containing key-value pairs to an array of objects in JavaScript

Tags: json

Can anyone help me on on this? 
I have JSON object as below

```
{
    "app_Welcome": "Welcome",
    "app_Notifications": "Notifications",
    "app_New": "New"
}
```

and I want to convert it to to an array of object

```
[
    {"app_Welcome": "Welcome"},
    {"app_Notifications": "Notifications"},
    {"app_New": "New"}
]
```

Thanks!

Comment: In what language?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert object containing Objects into array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26795643/how-to-convert-object-containing-objects-into-array-of-objects)

Comment: This is not a good programming question. What language? What have you tried?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```js
    var a = {
        "app_Welcome": "Welcome",
        "app_Notifications": "Notifications",
        "app_New": "New"
    };

    var result = [];
    for( var property in a) {
        var obj = {};
        obj[property] = a[property];
        result.push( obj ); 
    }
    
    console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks @YouneL for quick reply

Comment: this does not work, it puts every character into its own object