# angularJS: inline filter not working on ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am using angularJS v1.2.14.

This is my interface. The ng-repeat displays the info correctly, but the filter does not work. In other words, when I type text into the input box, this does not filter the ng-repeat data at all.

```
<input ng-model="searchbox" type="text" />

<section ng-repeat="tienda in datosTiendas | filter:searchbox | limitTo:1">
    <span>ven: {{tienda.ventaIndividualRedondeadaParaDisplay}}</span>
    <span>cum: {{tienda.cumplimientoIndividualParaDisplay}}</span>
    <span>CO: {{tienda.CO}}</span>  
</section>
```

This is my model:

```
$scope.datosTiendas={};
$scope.datosTiendas={"0":{"tienda":"DE LA CUESTA-BUCARAMANGA","venta":"134960","CO":64,"nombre":"DELACUESTA","coordinadorID":5,"cuota":874000,"cumplimiento":0.15441647597254005,"anoPasado":504600,"crecimiento":-0.7325406262386048,"ventaIndividualRedondeadaParaDisplay":"135","puestoEnVentasTiendas":38,"cumplimientoIndividualParaDisplay":15,"nombreTiendaParaDisplay":"DELACUESTA","crecimientoIndividualParaDisplay":-73,"crecimientoIndividualPesosRedondeadaParaDisplay":"-$370","cuotaIndividualRedondeadaParaDisplay":"$874"},"1":{"tienda":"AZUCAR PALMIRA UNICENTRO","venta":"179820","CO":59,"nombre":"UNICE PALM","coordinadorID":3,"cuota":874000,"cumplimiento":0.2057437070938215,"anoPasado":999003,"crecimiento":-0.8200005405389174,"ventaIndividualRedondeadaParaDisplay":"180","puestoEnVentasTiendas":37,"cumplimientoIndividualParaDisplay":20,"nombreTiendaParaDisplay":"UNICE PALM","crecimientoIndividualParaDisplay":-82,"crecimientoIndividualPesosRedondeadaParaDisplay":"-$819","cuotaIndividualRedondeadaParaDisplay":"$874"},"2":{"tienda":"NUESTRO MONTERIA","venta":"233660","CO":69,"nombre":"NUES MONTE","coordinadorID":4,"cuota":1150000,"cumplimiento":0.20318260869565216,"anoPasado":"NULL","crecimiento":"NULL","ventaIndividualRedondeadaParaDisplay":"234","puestoEnVentasTiendas":36,"cumplimientoIndividualParaDisplay":20,"nombreTiendaParaDisplay":"NUES MONTE","crecimientoIndividualParaDisplay":null,"crecimientoIndividualPesosRedondeadaParaDisplay":null,"cuotaIndividualRedondeadaParaDisplay":"$1.150"},"3":{"tienda":"AZUCAR FLORENCIA CAQUETA","venta":"239730","CO":58,"nombre":"FLORENCIA","coordinadorID":1,"cuota":943000,"cumplimiento":0.254220572640509,"anoPasado":984900,"crecimiento":-0.7565945781297594,"ventaIndividualRedondeadaParaDisplay":"240","puestoEnVentasTiendas":35,"cumplimientoIndividualParaDisplay":25,"nombreTiendaParaDisplay":"FLORENCIA","crecimientoIndividualParaDisplay":-75,"crecimientoIndividualPesosRedondeadaParaDisplay":"-$745","cuotaIndividualRedondeadaParaDisplay":"$943"},"4":{"tienda":"CALI CR 7","venta":"242920","CO":70,"nombre":"OUTLET K7","coordinadorID":3,"cuota":1023000,"cumplimiento":0.23745845552297165,"anoPasado":"NULL","crecimiento":"NULL","ventaIndividualRedondeadaParaDisplay":"243","puestoEnVentasTiendas":34,"cumplimientoIndividualParaDisplay":23,"nombreTiendaParaDisplay":"OUTLET K7","crecimientoIndividualParaDisplay":null,"crecimientoIndividualPesosRedondeadaParaDisplay":null,"cuotaIndividualRedondeadaParaDisplay":"$1.023"},"5":{"tienda":"AZUCAR SOLEDAD ATLANTICO","venta":"294950","CO":57,"nombre":"SOLEDAD","coordinadorID":4,"cuota":1357000,"cumplimiento":0.21735445836403833,"anoPasado":232899,"crecimiento":0.26642879531470726,"ventaIndividualRedondeadaParaDisplay":"295","puestoEnVentasTiendas":33,"cumplimientoIndividualParaDisplay":21,"nombreTiendaParaDisplay":"SOLEDAD","crecimientoIndividualParaDisplay":"+26","crecimientoIndividualPesosRedondeadaParaDisplay":"+$62","cuotaIndividualRedondeadaParaDisplay":"$1.357"}};
```

**Here is a jsFiddle, showing the exact problem: https://jsfiddle.net/0ptsuzwo/**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ng-repeat is made for an array of objects, not an object of objects.

I converted my model from an object to an array and it worked:

```
$scope.datosTiendas=Object.values($scope.datosTiendas)
```

Thank you to this answer on how to convert object of objects to array of objects:
[How to convert object containing Objects into array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26795643/how-to-convert-object-containing-objects-into-array-of-objects)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to filter objects with a string. You need to add the property you would like to filter to the `filter` part of your `ng-repeat`. You can choose whichever property you would like, for this example I am choosing `ventaIndividualRedondeadaParaDisplay`.

```
<section ng-repeat="tienda in datosTiendas | filter: { ventaIndividualRedondeadaParaDisplay: searchbox } | limitTo:1">
```

Comment: no luck, result is the same, text input does not filter. Your way makes more sense than my way, but my way works in other modules I have built. It searches through the whole array instead of just one property.

Comment: @quelquecosa I would expect both ways to work. Which version of angularjs are you using? And can you put the minimum code needed into a jsfiddle to replicate it there? It will be a lot easier to help you that way.

Comment: JSfiddle added to question

Comment: I'm using angularJS v1.2.14