# pushing an object into an array of objects

Tags: javascript

i want to push my retrieved results which is an inline string result to my array object item

Here is my code :

```
  arrayObject.push({ type: "type", item: itemArray });

  arrayObject.forEach((elementItem) => {
    global.forEach((element) => {
      const { items } = element;
      for (const item in items) {
        const title = items[item].title;
        elementItem.item.push({ title });
      }
    });
  });
```

And here is my json file that i retrieve from global, items and title

```
  global: [
    {
      items: {
        xxx: {
          title: 'result1',
        }
      },
    }
 ]
```

The result i want is like this :

```
[ { type: 'xxx', item: [ {name: result1 } ] } ]
```

Comment: what is global? what is collectionObject?

Comment: @JosefKatič same results

Comment: your code doesnt make sense you havent supplied everything

Comment: @JoeWarner global is just a json object i get from another file, and items is an object inside of it that i retrieve. i loop through it to get every title object inside items.

Comment: please supply them. so we know whats going on you shouldnt need 3 nested loops to achieve what you want

Comment: This might help you! In what you are trying to achieve https://stackoverflow.com/a/46269007/2199092

Comment: it is actually a simple thing to do ... but you made it very complicated.

Comment: @JoeWarner i just updated my question

Comment: answered any questions let me know and i'll try get back to you asap

Comment: @brxnzaz where does type come from i've just assumed its from way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here i've used reduce and object.values to produce your expected outcome.

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce
>
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values
>
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

```js
const global = [{
    way: 'type1',
    items: {
      get: {
        title: 'result1',
      },
      post: {
        title: 'result2',
      },
      put: {
        title: 'result3',
      },
    },
  },
  {
    way: 'type2',
    items: {
      get: {
        title: 'test1',
      },
      post: {
        title: 'test2',
      },
      put: {
        title: 'test3',
      },
    },
  },
]

function mapJsonToTypes(arr) {
  const typeAndTitles = (acc, {items, way: type}) => {
    return [...acc, {type, item: getTitlesFromItems(items)}]
  }

  return arr.reduce(typeAndTitles, []);
}

function getTitlesFromItems(items = {}) {
  return Object.values(items).map(({ title }) => title)
}



console.log(mapJsonToTypes(global));
```

Comment: awesome whack that like if it helped :) have a nice day.