# How to convert object with key/value 's to Array of Objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

Given a Javascript object with key values to Array of objects?

Example:

```
var data = { id: 1, first_name: "George", last_name: "Bluth", avatar: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/calebogden/128.jpg" }
```

Result should be:

```
[
  { id: 1, first_name: "George", last_name: "Bluth", avatar: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/calebogden/128.jpg" }
]
```

Comment: Have you tried anything at all? If yes please post the code.

Comment: I referred this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26795643/how-to-convert-object-containing-objects-into-array-of-objects. But the result it gets, i dont want that @KrishnaPrashatt

Comment: How JS object is invalid? I have just made for an example, if its wrong i will modify the example @AmardeepBhowmick

Comment: right, now ... so, just `data = [data]` should do it

Comment: `var result = []; result.push(data);`

Comment: @YashSangai you haven't try anything to do this . Please try first at your end then post your question here with what you have done .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do `[data]`:

```js
var data = { id: 1, first_name: "George", last_name: "Bluth", avatar: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/calebogden/128.jpg" };
var arr = [data];
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have `data` as it is, and want it in an array

```
data = [data];
```

see snippet

```js
var data = { id: 1, first_name: "George", last_name: "Bluth", avatar: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/calebogden/128.jpg" }

data = [data];

console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array and initialize it with the `data` variable:

```js
const data = { id: 1, first_name: "George", last_name: "Bluth", avatar: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/calebogden/128.jpg" };
const result = [data];

console.log(result);
```

Comment: How is your answer different than @Jack Bashford's ?

Comment: @OnurArı I just didn't copied from him.. the difference is that he answered a few seconds before me