# How t convert JavaScript objects into array of objects?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, json, object

I want to convert objects as shown here to array of objects:

My code:

```
entireObject =   {
        "++255 638-1527": {
            "email": "info@gmail.com",
            "phoneNumber": "++255 638-1527"
        },
        "+255 532-1587": {
            "email": "uihy@gmail.com",
            "phoneNumber": "+255 532-1587"
        },
        "+255 613-1587": {
            "email": "klch@gmail.com",
            "phoneNumber": "+255 613-1587",
            "info": [
                {
                    "date": "2022-02-19",
                    "count": 1
                },
                {
                    "date": "2022-03-17",
                    "count": 9
                }]
       }
}
```

I want to convert this to array of objects so, the output should look like this:

```
entireObject =   [
        {
            "email": "info@gmail.com",
            "phoneNumber": "++255 638-1527"
        },
            "email": "uihy@gmail.com",
            "phoneNumber": "+255 532-1587"
        },
        {
            "email": "klch@gmail.com",
            "phoneNumber": "+255 613-1587",
            "info": [
                {
                    "date": "2022-02-19",
                    "count": 1
                },
                {
                    "date": "2022-03-17",
                    "count": 9
                }]
            }
}
```

I need the data like this in order to render it in HTML, so How can I do this?

Comment: `Object.values(entireObject)`?

Comment: @evolutionxbox No change, if I do that

Comment: No change? What do you mean? The code I suggested won't affect `entireObject`, but it does return the array you want. Put it in a new variable

Comment: yeah I have put it in a seperate varibale and console.log() it

Comment: Please share that and update the question?

Comment: Please share what you have tried and the specific challenge with it so that we may assist you in fixing it.

Comment: NOTE: Your "desired output" is an invalid object as you have it now

Answer (score -1, accepted):

How about this?

```js
const myObject = {
  "++255 638-1527": {
    email: "info@gmail.com",
    phoneNumber: "++255 638-1527"
  },
  "+255 532-1587": {
    email: "uihy@gmail.com",
    phoneNumber: "+255 532-1587"
  },
  "+255 613-1587": {
    email: "klch@gmail.com",
    phoneNumber: "+255 613-1587",
    info: [{
        date: "2022-02-19",
        count: 1
      },
      {
        date: "2022-03-17",
        count: 9
      }
    ]
  }
};

let objectToArray = [{ ...myObject
}]

console.log(objectToArray)
```

Comment: This doesn't result in the desired output

Answer (score 1):

The desired result should end with `]` in order to be a valid array, not `}`. All you need is `Object.values()` as in the following demo.

```js
const entireObject =   {
        "++255 638-1527": {
            "email": "info@gmail.com",
            "phoneNumber": "++255 638-1527"
        },
        "+255 532-1587": {
            "email": "uihy@gmail.com",
            "phoneNumber": "+255 532-1587"
        },
        "+255 613-1587": {
            "email": "klch@gmail.com",
            "phoneNumber": "+255 613-1587",
            "info": [
                {
                    "date": "2022-02-19",
                    "count": 1
                },
                {
                    "date": "2022-03-17",
                    "count": 9
                }]
       }
};

const arr = Object.values( entireObject );

console.log( arr );
```

Answer (score -1):

you could do something like this:

```js
const myObject = {
  "++255 638-1527": {
    email: "info@gmail.com",
    phoneNumber: "++255 638-1527"
  },
  "+255 532-1587": {
    email: "uihy@gmail.com",
    phoneNumber: "+255 532-1587"
  },
  "+255 613-1587": {
    email: "klch@gmail.com",
    phoneNumber: "+255 613-1587",
    info: [{
        date: "2022-02-19",
        count: 1
      },
      {
        date: "2022-03-17",
        count: 9
      }
    ]
  }
};

let result = Object.values(myObject).map((item) => ({ ...item
}));
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Why use `map` here? It seems pointless

Answer (score -1):

Just wanted to point you in the right direction as a similar question was asked and perfectly answered. Here's the link: [How to convert object containing Objects into array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26795643/how-to-convert-object-containing-objects-into-array-of-objects)
N.B. please make sure to see the answer which is voted as the best answer.

Comment: Rather than a link answer you should vote to close as a duplicate

Comment: Mark Schultheiss, I found it interesting that you voted my attempt to direct the asker to the solution down.
Anyways, it was my very first answer and I will try to do better next time.

Comment: Please do not assume votes here as I did not vote you up or down.