# Unexplained Javascript error

Tags: javascript

I'm getting this exception in the following code: TypeError: Cannot read
property 'toString' of undefined

```
for (var key in obj) {
  var val = obj[key];
  var s = val.toString();
}
```

How is it possible for val to be undefined in this code?

I don't have a log of the actual data, so I'm not sure what was in obj, but it was constructed from JSON and I don't have the JSON input.

This is the actual full code:

```
function deepMatchKeyword(obj, keyword) {
    for (var key in obj) {
        var val = obj[key];
        if (typeof val == 'object' && !(val instanceof Array)) {
            if (deepMatchKeyword(val, keyword))
                return true;
        } else {
            var s = val.toString();
            if (s.toLowerCase().includes(keyword))
                return true;
       }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: It's not really unexplained is it, `val` is not defined, probably because `obj[key]` is undefined

Comment: `var obj = {a: undefined};` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How is it possible for val to be undefined in this code?

Very easily. `undefined` is a value like any other and can be assigned to a property.

`for ... in` deals with enumerable properties, not just ones with defined values.

```js
var obj = {
  someProperty: undefined
};


for (var key in obj) {
  var val = obj[key];
  var s = val.toString();
}
```

Comment: Oh right, that makes sense.  I don't think JSON.parse would return anything like that but I do have some post-processing stuff that is maybe causing that.

Answer (score 0):

It's very common to include the hasOwnProperty check in loops over properties, in order to avoid enumerable properties inherited from the object's prototype chain.

```
// obj is defined earlier

for (var key in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        var val = obj[key];
        var s = val.toString();
    }
}
```

See e.g. [for..in and hasOwnProperty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12735778/for-in-and-hasownproperty).