# Is this `if` statement redundant?

Tags: javascript

I found this snippet in some documentation.  Is the `if` statement redundant?

```
for (var key in contactData) {
    if (contactData.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        // Omitted
    }
}
```

I tried this out in my browser console and both `for` loops printed out the same thing.

```
contactData = {};
contactData.a = 1;
contactData.b = 2;
for (var key in contactData) {
    if (contactData.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        console.log(key);
    }
}
for (var key in contactData) {
    console.log(key);
}
```

Comment: Not exactly redundant, but rather possibly harmful. What if you had a contact with the name `hasOwnProperty`?

Comment: I was going to say it was duplicate of [for..in and hasOwnProperty](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12735778/for-in-and-hasownproperty)

Comment: I agree with @Theraot and disagree with @deceze♦

Comment: The check is only required as a guard to code that incorrectly/questionably adds an enumerable property to Object.prototype (in this case the object used as the source is trivially a plain object without a special prototype chain)