# How to have optional arguments in javascript

Tags: javascript

The following function creates input fields where the user specifies type, name and a number of classes that he would like to add for the input element. Sometimes, the user is going to want to set other attributes for the element, such as `step`, or any other DOM attribute. That's why I want to use optional arguments:

```
function createInputField(type, name, classList, optional){
    var input = document.createElement('input');
    input.type = type;
    input.name = name;

    for(var i=0; i<classList.length; i++){
        input.classList.add(classList[i]);
    }

    for(key,value) in optional{ // Ugly fake code. How do I implement this in Javascript?
        input.getAttribute(key) = value;
    }    

    return input;
}

input = createInputField("number", "numberfield", ["red", "top"], {"step":"0.05"})
```

How do I implement this functionality in Javascript?

Comment: Which version of JS are you supporting/targeting? Are you talking about [`...rest` parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters)? An `options` object? JS doesn't require the function to be called with the number of parameters it defines, you can access all of them via [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments).

Comment: See [Default parameters - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/tr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters).

Comment: `if (optional) Object.keys(optional).forEach(k => input.setAttribute(k, optional[k]));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use normal object enumeration:

```
for (var key in optional) {
    var value = optional[key];
    input.setAttribute(key, value);
}
```

This doesn't have to do anything with the argument `optional` itself being optional so that you can omit it in the call. Just provide an empty object (`{}`) when you don't want to pass any extra dom attributes.

If you want to be able to completely omit it (like calling `createInputField("number", "x", ["red"])`, you can either wrap the loop inside an `if (typeof optional == "object")` condition, or you use [default parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/tr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters):

```
function createInputField(type, name, classList = [], optional = {}) {
    …
}
```

Comment: Bergi, it appears that your code generates an error, since `input.getAttribute(key) = value;` seems to generate `ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment`. I have edited it to correct the error.

Comment: @Sandi Yeah, thanks, I just blindly copied the assignment line from the OP.

Answer (score 1):

This is what you need:

```
if(optional && typeof optional === 'object') {
   for(var key in optional) {
      if(input.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
         input.getAttribute(key) = optional[key];
      }
   } 
}
```

Comment: It was like pseudo code. I update it now, thanks lofihelsinki!

Comment: One more thing, needs to be `if(optional.hasOwnProperty(key))`

Comment: Why? We are in for each loop, that guarantees the optional[key] existence.

Comment: You need to check if the property `key` belongs to Object `optional` and is not i.e. a property inherited from a prototype class. Those might be included in the loop too. It is explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12735778/for-in-and-hasownproperty

Comment: Thanks, i got it.

Comment: @lofihelsinki [N, it doesn't need to](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45014721/1048572).

Comment: That's right in this example, since we know `optional` is just a plain object: `{"step":"0.05"}`. However, there's nothing to prohibit passing a non-plain object to the function `createInputField`. So we can't be sure `optional` doesn't i.e. extend some other type of object. Therefore i would add `hasOwnProperty`