# Javascript; is this use of "hasOwnProperty" redundant?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

Looking through some of our app code I found the following:

```
for (prop in aBunchOfData.properties) {
  if (!aBunchOfData.properties.hasOwnProperty(prop)) continue;
  doABunchOfProcessing(aBunchOfData.properties[prop]);
}
```

As far as I understand, `for ... in` will only loop through the "own" properties of an object. **Can the `hasOwnProperty` check here ever make a difference? If so, under what conditions?**

Thanks!

Comment: It's more common to use `Object.entries` or `Object.values` now

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12735778/for-in-and-hasownproperty

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. The `in` operator ascends the prototype chain, while `.hasOwnProperty()` does not. Using that `if` statement ensures that only properties on the object itself will be included. To avoid having to use the check, you can use `Object.keys()`, which does not ascend the prototype chain.

Comment: Just to elaborate, `in` iterates all _enumerable_ keys, and `Object.keys()` iterates all _own enumerable_ keys. Neither iterates non-enumerable keys, though `.hasOwnProperty()` will return `true` for own, non-enumerable keys.

Comment: Thanks Patrick, your mention of enumerability clarified it! I was looking at all these answers thinking "I've iterated over `Object` instances a million times without `hasOwnProperty`, and I've never seen `toString`, `valueOf`, etc, pop up"

Comment: @GershomMaes To tack on even more, on the off chance you have `Symbol` keys, they aren't enumerable either, which provides a _minimal_ layer of safety.

Answer (score 1):

It is useful because a `for in` loop will check all object properties including prototype props.  This is inefficient so checking `hasOwnProperty` limits the loop to properties that are unique to that object.  The preferred way to loop is:

```
Object.keys(myObject).forEach(()=> // do stuff)
```

`map` can also me used as an iterator here.

Comment: Can `map` be used as an iterator though? I feel like that wouldn't work, as `Object.keys()` _creates_ an array, though I could be wrong on that.

Comment: If you're referring to what gets mutated, there is more to that story, yes.  But you can definitely map over the array that results from `Object.keys()`.