# Alternative to use eval in "for"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I use the following function to dynamically check the properties of a variable number of objects.

```
// FUNCTION: Check Objects
var ObjectsN = 4;
function CheckObjects()
{
        for (var i=0; i<=ObjectsN; i++)
        {
            if ((eval("Object"+i+".property")==0)
            {
                if (i==ObjectsN)
                {
                    alert("Function finished");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return; // end function
            }
        }
}
```

I need to check if each object has the same property value. 
Is there a way to do the same without using eval ?
A real example would be really much appreciated.

Comment: *variable number of objects*, if only there was an `Array` type in JavaScript... :P

Comment: ..so I should tell each object it should register in a array?

Comment: For starters, have a look at [`hasOwnProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) instead of using eval.

Comment: That's what I'd do. Save having to use `eval()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The structure you're looking for is an [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array). So use an array to store your objects:

```
/* assuming `var Object1 = new Object(), Object2 = new Object();` and so on */
var objs = [ Object1, Object2, Object3 ];
```

Then testing for a property should implement [`hasOwnProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) while iterating:

```
for (var o = 0; i < objs.length; o++){
  if (objs[o].hasOwnProperty('property')){
    // Property exists, test its value:
  }
}
```

You could then test against `objs[o].property` to retrieve its value and see if it matches what you're expecting.

And for those browsers that may not have the function available, here is a cross-browser version of `hasOwnProperty` ([source](https://gist.github.com/332357), but originally from  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/135448/how-do-i-check-to-see-if-an-object-has-an-attribute-in-javascript)):

```
/*
Cross-browser hasOwnProperty solution, based on answers from:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/135448/how-do-i-check-to-see-if-an-object-has-an-attribute-in-javascript
*/
if ( !Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty ) {
  Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty = function(prop) {
    var proto = obj.__proto__ || obj.constructor.prototype;
    return (prop in this) && (!(prop in proto) || proto[prop] !== this[prop]);
  };
}
```

Comment: My objects are also variable, so I don't know how many are there. So should I tell each object (when it is created) to add itself to the objs array ?

Comment: You can do that, yes. Assuming the `objs` (in this example) is global scope, you could place `objs.push(this)` in the object construct to maintain a list of objects that have been built.

Comment: @cocoacoder: Here's an example of what I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/bradchristie/4Q8d5/1/

Comment: The alternative `hasOwnProperty` function is inappropriate here (and pretty awful in general), it will fail if the constructor property points to the wrong object, which is fairly common, or there is more than one object on the `[[Prototype]]` chain (other than `null`) which is also quite common.  A much better alternative is [`propertyIsEnumerable`](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.2.4.7), which gives identical results in this case (but not for non–enumerable properties of course) and was the common solution for old Safari versions that were missing `hasOwnProperty`.

Comment: @BradChristie—that's ok, it wasn't your function. :-)

Comment: mh .. using ObjectsArray.push($(this.id)); only adds "object object" to the array, not the name of the object

Comment: @cocoacoder: that's becase you're wrapping it in a jQuery object. You have to remember `el`!=`$(el)`; but `el`==`$(el)[0]`.

Comment: @BradChristie OK, I got it working with the array ! However I still can't get it working with the array creation on the fly:

for (var i = 1; i <= Objects; i++)
    ObjectsArray.push("Obj" + i)

As the result is interpreted as a string, instead of objects

Comment: @cocoacoder: Take a look at the jsfiddle I posted and how the object (at the bottom) automatically adds the new objects to an array. Also, look at the `for` statement and how I iterate over the list of objects that have been stored.

Answer (score 2):

assuming `Object0`, `Object1`, `Object2`,`Object3` & `Object4` are global variables.

you could access the variables by using `window`

```
var ObjectsN = 4;
function CheckObjects()
{
    for (var i=0; i<=ObjectsN; i++)
    {
        if (window['Object'+i].property == 0)
        {
            if (i==ObjectsN)
            {
                alert("Function finished");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return; // end function
        }
    }
```

}

Comment: I would also include `if (window['Object'+i] && window['Object'+i].property == 0)` in case the object is null or undefined

Comment: @andres yes indeed, but that's up to the OP to do the checking

Comment: so with this method I don't have to use an array ? Only adding window with brackets, right ?

Comment: yes, this solution requires no array. However, for best practice or readability, `Array` solution is recommended.

Comment: I'm not expert in evaluating JavaScript performance, however, if your number of variables is going to be large (100+), `Array` solution is strongly recommended, if you are doing experiment/proof of concept/debugging, then stick to `window`

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you are thinking about numbering variables. Use an array instead.

Don't have `Object1`, `Object2`, etc. Have `[ x, y, x ]`

Then you can do:

```
for (var i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
    var obj = objects[i];
    if ("property" in obj) {
        // Whatever
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar to Neverever's answer, but passing a reference to the global object instead of assuming there's a `window` object available.

```
var ObjectsN = 4;
var CheckObjects = (function(global) {

    for (var i=0; i<=ObjectsN; i++) {
        if ( global['Object' + i].property == 0) {
            if (i == ObjectsN) {
                alert("Function finished");
            }
        } else {
            return; // end function
        }
    }
}
```

Are you sure that `== 0` is the test you want? That will return true even if the property doesn't exist. The function isn't particularly robust, if an object from 0 to n doesn't exist, an error will be thrown.

The function will continue only as long as `Objectn.property == 0` returns true, so it will exit as soon as it gets a truethy result (e.g. `Object0.property = 'foo'`).

Comment: thanks for your answer, so should I add (as previously suggested)
`if (global['Object'+i] && global['Object'+i].property == 0)` to make sure the object exists ?

Comment: also do you consider using global or an array better for performance?

Comment: Performance difference is trivial, much better to use an array, see Brad's answer.

Comment: thanks.
BTW: I think the else block isn't redundant as it exits the function without having to continue the for statement if one object has already another value than 0. Right?

Comment: `if (global['Object'+i] && global['Object'+i].property == 0)` is better. Yes, the `else` block does something, I read the test backwards initially.