# JavaScript check if property defined

Tags: javascript

What is the recommended way to check if an object property like obj.prop.otherprop.another is defined?

```
if(obj && obj.prop && obj.prop.otherprop && obj.prop.otherprop.another)
```

this works well, but enough ugly.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/135448/how-do-i-check-to-see-if-an-object-has-a-property-in-javascript

Comment: @JonH no, not really...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most efficient way to do it is by checking for obj.prop.otherprop.another in a try{} catch(exception){} block. That would be the fastest if all the remaining exist; else the exception would be handled.

```
var a = null;
try {
  a = obj.prop.otherprop.another;
} catch(e) {
  obj = obj || {};
  obj.prop = obj.prop || {};
  obj.prop.otherprop = obj.prop.otherprop || {};
  obj.prop.otherprop.another = {};
  a = obj.prop.otherprop.another ;
}
```

Comment: Please don't use this.. this is just stupid of me to suggest this.

Answer (score 0):

Not saying this is better but ...

```
x = null
try {
  x = obj.prop.otherprop.another;
} catch() {}
// ...
```

Or alternatively ...

```
function resolve(obj, path) {
  path = path.split('.');
  while (path.length && obj) obj = obj[path.shift()];
  return obj;
}

x = resolve(obj, 'prop.otherprop.another');
```

... but I guess the actual answer is that there isn't a best-practice for this.  Not that I'm aware of.

Answer (score 0):

If you're in a silly mood, this would work:

```
if ((((obj || {}).prop || {}).anotherprop || {}).another) { ... }
```

But I don't know if initializing three new objects is really worth not having to repeatedly type out the path.