# JavaScript Possible Iteration Over Unexpected

Tags: javascript

I have the following code:

```
  for (i in awards) {
         if (awards[i] instanceof Array === false) {
               console.log(awards[i]);
                httpFactory.patch(awards[i], {"read": true}, false);
             }
       }
```

My IDE shows this error relating to the code above:

> Possible iteration over unexpected (custom / inherited) members,
>   probably missing hasOwnProperty check
>
> Checks for any instances of unfiltered for-in loops in JavaScript. The
>   use of this construct results in processing inherited or unexpected
>   properties. You need to filter own properties with hasOwnProperty()
>   method. The validation works in JavaScript, html or jsp files.

Could you explain in more detail what is meant by this statement?

Comment: jQuery doesn't perform `hasOwnProperty` checks - I wonder how many warnings that would produce....

Answer (score 188, accepted):

The IDE is recommending that you add a test:

```
if (awards.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
    ...
}
```

inside the `for` loop.

I personally recommend not doing this, and disabling the warning if possible.  There's simply no need in most code, and even less need in ES5 code where you can safely add non-enumerable properties to an object using `Object.defineProperty`

The `hasOwnProperty` check is only necessary if you have unsafely added new (enumerable) properties to `Object.prototype`, so the simplest fix is *don't do that*.

jQuery doesn't perform this test - they [explicitly document](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/5499) that jQuery will break if `Object.prototype` is unsafely modified.

Comment: In IntelliJ 15, to disable the warning, perform the following: Open Preferences -> Editor -> Code Style -> Inspections.  In the search box, enter "hasOwnProperty". It will display "Unfiltered for..in loop". Uncheck that box. Click OK button to accept change and close the window.

Comment: In IntelliJ: CTRL ALT S (unless you're using Ubuntu which has its own CTRL ALT S shortcut) just search for "hasOwnProperty" and you'll get straight to the problem, uncheck it and it's done!

Comment: In WebStorm, go to File...Settings, then Editor -> Inspections -> "JavaScript and TypeScript" -> General, and uncheck "Unfiltered for..in loop".

Comment: @Machtyn There is no need to go to settings to disable this warning. On Linux/Windows, press Alt + Enter with the cursor over the warning, select the first option on the context menu that popups and disable the setting in the submenu next to the first option.

Answer (score 29):

Every object in javascript has prototype which has its own properties(native/inherited methods/properties) and properties which are directly attached to object itself.

When you iterate over an object, it will iterate the properties of the object itself and the properties of the prototype of the object.

So, In order to avoid iterating over the prototype, it is recommended to use [hasOwnProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) method which return true only when the object has the mentioned property directly. i.e, Not inside prototype

Example

```
for (var k in object) {
  if (object.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
     // do your computation here.
  }
}
```

More details can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/135448/how-do-i-check-to-see-if-an-object-has-a-property-in-javascript)

Answer (score 27):

You can also refactor your loop into:

```
const keys = Object.keys(object);
for (const key of keys){
   // do something with object[key];
}
```

Answer (score 17):

Also you can get rid of the warning writing a forEach loop for a more readable and functional approach:

```
Object.keys(object).forEach(key => {
    // Do something with object[key]
});
```

Answer (score -4):

you should add one more condition at the beginning of this loop

```
if (awards.hasOwnProperty(i))
```

Comment: I voted this answer down, so I think it's polite if I say why. This answer says how to avoid the warning but it doesn't explain what the warning means, how this avoids it, or what the this code does.