# How to check if an object nested in a property of another object as a property?

Tags: javascript

I have an object nested within a property of a parent object. I need to find out if `a` property exist.

```
var o = {
 prop: {
       a: 'a',
       b: 'b' 
    }
}
```

Here are two approaches:

```
o.prop.hasOwnProperty('a'); // true

!!o.prop.a // true
```

What is the difference between the two? Any other alternatives?

Comment: Please check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/135448/how-do-i-check-if-an-object-has-a-property-in-javascript. It does not really matter that your object is nested.

Comment: useful article: http://toddmotto.com/methods-to-determine-if-an-object-has-a-given-property/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is that the first example (`hasOwnProperty`) is ensuring that the property wasn't passed down the prototype chain, while the second would pass where 'a' was inherited from the prototype chain. You could also check using:

```
('a' in o.prop)
```

Comment: just a quick question, please.. I have a scenario where I need to check prop first before a.. what could be an concise way.. maybe ... ('prop' in o) && ('a' in o.prop) what do you suggest? thanks for your help

Comment: As ugly as it is, yes, that is a typical approach for testing nested properties:  `if(prop.o && prop.o.a){ ... }`. The `'attr' in object` syntax is nice, but I typically use it for dynamic attribute/function names.