# Javascript: check if an object within a multidimensional array has a certain property and then remove that object

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array, like this:

```
[
    [ 
        { name: "jeff", job: "cleaner" }, 
        { name: "kate", job: "cashier" } 
    ],
    [ 
        { name: "alice", job: "engineer" },
        { name: "sean", job: "writer" },
        { name: "ruby", job: "police officer" }
    ],
    [ 
        { name: "sarah", job: "writer" }, 
        { name: "john", job: "cleaner" } 
    ]
]
```

I'm looking for a fast and concise way to find an object within this structure where one of the properties matches a certain value and then remove that object entirely.

For example, say I want to find all objects where the property of `job` is `writer` and remove those objects from the structure.

Please bare in mind that I would **like keep the current structure of this array completely intact**, with just the relevant objects removed.

Comment: [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) is your friend, though it does not edit in place - otherwise check [`_.remove`](https://lodash.com/docs#remove), to be iterated on every entry of the outermost array.

Comment: What is the purpose of the outer array? Will the relevant inner array always be at [0]?

Comment: @DylanWatt The structure represents rows and columns. And yes, all the inner arrays will always be at that level - the structure will not get any deeper.

Comment: Seems simple enough. Where are you stuck?

Comment: If you want to check the entire array, you're going to have to loop touching every object. Dare I mention the double-for-loop. There's **LOTS** of ways to do it, but the best solution depends on your specific situation. How big are these arrays? Are you able to coerce / retrieve the data in any other structure?

Comment: Thanks Alex, the arrays aren't much bigger than the example in the question, so I imagine looping isn't a big deal. Also I'm not able to retreive the data in any other structure.

Comment: Ok if you're talking < 1000 nodes, the double-for loop is your best bet.  Remember - Javascript is **LIGHTNING** fast when you don't touch the DOM.

Comment: What would you recommend for > 1000 nodes?

Comment: @shrewdbeans If you have enough nodes that you need to consider performance, you would want to look into maintaining a lookup map. {cleaner:[], writer:[]} etc.  That would allow fast lookup of each job, and the entities that contain it. However, how the lookup map is created/maintained is still an issue. In general, you have to get pretty large to need to do this. Javascript is amazing at arrays, I've dealt with 1 million+ sized arrays client side, and it handled it like a champ on modern CPU/browsers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used a `hasOwnProperty` function which I do not take credit for from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/135448/how-do-i-check-if-an-object-has-a-property-in-javascript).

You can do it like this, using that function:

```
arr.forEach(function (subArr, index, myArr) {
    myArr[index] = subArr.filter(function (obj) {
        if (hasOwnProperty(obj, "job") && obj["job"] === "writer") {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    });
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bky1n0kf/)

Comment: shorter: `return !(hasOwnProperty(obj, "job") && obj["job"] === "writer")`