# `if (0 in array)` — is this even legal?

Tags: javascript, syntax, cross-browser

For now I'm writing a complex of laboratory works about coding in JavaScript. I know that there is a construction like

```
if ('field' in object) {
    /* Do something with object.field */
}
```

to be used to determine that a variable called `field` really exists in `object` even if it equals to undefined.

And my Firefox Developer Edition 44 is able to determine if there is a field in an array like this:

```
if (0 in array) {
    /* Do something with first element */
}
```

**The question**: is this method legal? Is it a part of a living standard or not?

---

**What it is *supposed* to do**:
Let q be an array with such elements:

```
[ 5, <1 empty slot>, undefined, 5 ]
```

Then:

- `0 in q`, `2 in q`, `3 in q` equals to `true`;
- `1 in q` equals to `false`.

Comment: What do you mean by "`<1 empty slot>`"?

Comment: @hindmost: JavaScript arrays are inherently sparse. They can have empty elements.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder Yes, I know. But AFAIK such empty element is the same as `undefined`. So the OP's array sample seems ambiguous.

Comment: @hindmost: There's a significant difference between a property that doesn't exist *at all* and a property with the value `undefined`. Granted if you do `obj.prop`, in both cases the *result* is `undefined`, but the mechanism by which that happens is completely different. Missing-vs-present-with-undefined also has implications for `for-in` loops, `forEach`, `Object.keys`, ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> `if (0 in array)` — is this even legal?

Sure. The `in` operator checks to see if a property exists in the object (directly, or via the prototype chain). The left-hand operand is the name of the property, the right-hand operand is the object to check. If the left-hand operand isn't a string or `Symbol`, it's coerced to a string. This is all completely within [the specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html):

- [The `in` operator](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-relational-operators-runtime-semantics-evaluation) (scroll down to *RelationalExpression : RelationalExpression in ShiftExpression*)
- [The abstract `ToPropertyKey` operation](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-topropertykey)
- [The abstract `HasProperty` operation](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-hasproperty)

JavaScript's untyped arrays are objects (and [not really arrays](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2011/01/myth-of-arrays.html), although engines optimize that when they can). Array indexes are property names (and technically strings, though engines optimize that when they can). So you can use `in` to check if an array contains a property by using an "array index" with `in` and the array. (You can also use `hasOwnProperty`: `theArray.hasOwnProperty(0)`, but [it's slower with arrays on modern engines](http://jsperf.com/in-vs-hasownproperty-for-arrays).)

> What it is supposed to do:
>
> Let q be an array with such elements:
>
> ```
> [ 5, <1 empty slot>, undefined, 5 ]
> ```
>
> Then:
>
> - `0 in q`, `2 in q`, `3 in q` equals to `true`;
> - `1 in q` equals to `false`.

Yes, that's perfectly valid:

```js
var q = [];
q[0] = 5;
q[2] = undefined;
q[3] = 5;
for (var i = 0; i < q.length; ++i) {
  snippet.log(i + " in q? " + (i in q));
}
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="//tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Comment: [section 6.1.7.](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-object-type) Now I see @_@ 
@T.J. Crowder , thank you for such a detailed response 