# hasOwnProperty does not work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, http

I got a JSON object (`{error:true}`) from the server.

I try to check if the object contains the key "error" and either the key exists, the function `hasOwnProperty` returns `false`.

This is my code:

```
$http({
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8;' },
        url: '/Modules/Partners/Mailing/SendMail.ashx',
        data: $.param({ contact: JSON.stringify(contact), body: partnerObject.mailTemplate.longValue, title: "" }),
        method: 'POST'
    })
    .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log(data);
        console.log(data.hasOwnProperty('error'));

       if (data.hasOwnProperty('error')) {
           deferred.reject(contact);
       } else {
           deferred.resolve(contact);
       }
       //console.log(data)

    })
    .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        deferred.reject(contact);
    });
```

In the console I can see that the object contains the "error" key by the `hasOwnProperty('error')` returns `false`

[image]

Answer (score 6):

I think that the problem is with the JSON object you receive. In fact the key is not `error` but `'error'`. Try to see if `data.hasOwnProperty("'error'")` works.

Comment: just a note that with JSON Object's you must surround the key in quotation marks not single quotes " " as opposed too ' '

Otherwise its not valid!!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `in` operator to check if property exist on object/array.
It can be used like this `"error" in data` // will return true

Comment: Not quite; that will tell you if the object is iterable, according to https://stackoverflow.com/a/136411/8949477.

Answer (score 1):

Your `success` method receives `String` data, not `JSON`:

```
.success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
    var result = angular.fromJson(data);

    if (result.hasOwnProperty('error')) {
        deferred.reject(contact);
    } else {
        deferred.resolve(contact);
    }
    //console.log(data)
})
```

**BTW:** If it were JSON, in console, you would see:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using `if(data && data.error)` instead of `if (data.hasOwnProperty('error'))`

It's probably because the error property is inherited. See more about hasOwnProperty and inherited properties [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty)

Answer (score 0):

check the content-type of data sent from server. it should be 'application/json' then it gets converted to javascript object implicitly.
to check use "typeof data" it must be "object" else if its string then you need to parse it to object by using JSON.parse

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why but return the object like 
JsonSerializer.Serialize("{\"error\":true}");

Instead of
JsonSerializer.Serialize("{'error':true}");
or
JsonSerializer.Serialize("{error:true}");

Resolve my problem