# Why is NodeList.hasOwnProperty('length') returning true in safari 9.0.2?

Tags: javascript, safari

Here is an example.

```js
alert(document.querySelectorAll('span').hasOwnProperty('length'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably because hasOwnProperty does not work the same cross-browser, especially since the [change in April 2015](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/04/DOM-attributes-now-on-the-prototype-chain) (for Chrome here...):

Check and/or update your Safari, but it still might not work since obviously they are making changes.

Perhaps you can use a different approach which works the same cross-browser such as

- `if ('prop' in obj)`
- `if ('undefined' !== typeof obj['prop'])`

There's slight difference in performance which shouldn't be an issue for you I think. See also [this page](http://andrew.hedges.name/experiments/in/) for a reference.

See [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/135448/how-do-i-check-if-an-object-has-a-property-in-javascript) also.

Comment: Every other answer in any forum suggests that 'hasOwnProperty' is the preferred way to check if an object has a property.  I guess it used to work in safari prior to 9.0.2.

Comment: Yup, it seems it did work, but since they are obviously making changes I wouldn't force it.

Comment: 'prop' in obj will always return truthy value for prototype properties. typeof NodeList.length won't return undefined as expected in all browsers.