# Node.js : check if a property is absent from object

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I’m checking if a property 'lessons' (not inherited) is not present in obj, 
All these give me true

`(typeof obj['lessons'] == undefined)`

`(!(obj.hasOwnProperty('lessons')))`

`(!(hasOwnProperty.call(obj,'lessons')))`

`(!(_.has(obj, 'lessons')))`

`(!Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, 'lessons’))`

but the property is present in the object, when i print keys by using (key in obj). I don't want to use it as it's very slow and my object is huge.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/136411) on stackoverflow, but I don't understand what it's trying to do or how to use it with node.js.

I'd also like to know how are the mentioned ways of using `hasOwnProperty` are different.

**EDIT**
*adding code*

My code is:

```
console.log("LS:",JSON.stringify(obj)) ;
if (typeof obj['lessons'] == undefined)
    console.log('typeof undefined');
else {console.log('typeof not undefined');}

if (!(obj.hasOwnProperty('lessons')))
    console.log('hasOwnProperty: false');
else {console.log('hasOwnProperty not undefined');}

if (!(hasOwnProperty.call(obj,'lessons')))
    console.log('hasOwnProperty.call');
else {console.log('hasOwnProperty.call not undefined');}

if (!(_.has(obj, 'lessons')))
    console.log('_.hash');
else {console.log('_has not undefined');}

if (!(_.has(obj, 'lessons')))
    {obj['lessons'] = {"levels": []};}
else
    {console.log("has lesson level ");}

console.log("Lesson ", JSON.stringify(obj.lessons));
```

And the output I'm getting is:

```
LS: {"_id":"N9zmznzAWx","time":"1970-01-01T00:33:36.000Z","lessons":{"levels":["abc"]}}
typeof not undefined
hasOwnProperty: false
hasOwnProperty.call
_.hash
Lesson {"levels":[]}
```

Same case with all others..

**SOLUTION**
It works when I use JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj)) instead of obj.

Comment: try to check with dot operator (obj.lessons)

Comment: Have you tried simply `if ( ! ('lessons' in obj)) { ... }`

Comment: `(key in obj)` *does* take into account inherited properties. If the `in` operator is what you are looking for, then you should use it.

Comment: Please show us how you did construct your `obj`, so that we can tell what properties it really has (where, and with what attributes).

Comment: it works perfectly as expected [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mnjztc86/) it doesnt log response. can you replicate a your issue in fiddle ?

Comment: Uh, the output of `JSON.stringify` says *nothing* about what your object really is. Please show us where you got it from, and how it was constructed.

Comment: @Bergi I used the wrong case, updated the question.
I am getting the object from mongoDB using mongoose and editing it.

Comment: @Shipra: Well *that* is significant information. You might have better luck trying your tests against `obj.toJSON()` instead of `obj` itself.

Comment: Don't use `hasOwnProperty.call`. Maybe `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call` or `({}).hasOwnProperty.call`. But the [[Prototype]] internal slot of the global object is implementation dependent, so better don't assume it inherits from `Object.prototype`.

Comment: @Bergi I'm getting 
_TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'toJSON'_

Answer (score 1):

Your checks aren't working because Mongoose document objects don't use simple object properties to expose their fields.

Instead, you can use the [`Document#get`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-get) method to do this (with your `obj` renamed to `doc`):

```
var isMissing = (doc.get('lessons') === undefined);
```

Or you can create a plain JS object from your document by calling [`toObject()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-toObject) on it, and then use `hasOwnProperty` on that:

```
var obj = doc.toObject();
var isMissing = !obj.hasOwnProperty('lessons');
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function that I wrote as an example to test three ways you have listed in your question:

```
function check(obj) {
  if (!obj.hasOwnProperty("lessons")) {
    console.log('nope');
  }  
  if (!_.has(obj, 'lessons')) {
    console.log('nope');
  }  
  if (!obj.lessons) {
    console.log('nope');
  }
}
```

Here is JSBIN that runs the function on two objects, one with 'lessons' and one without:

[Example JsBIN](https://jsbin.com/pemuhuc/edit?js,console)

Answer (score 0):

## typeof returns a string

```
var obj = {};
console.log(typeof (typeof obj.lessons));
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0ar2ku7v/

So you must compare it as such:

```
if (typeof obj.lessons === 'undefined')
  console.log('nope');
```