# To check the JavaScript object has a value

Tags: javascript

Can you tell me how to check the JavaScript object has a value ? This `vm.occupantDetail.contactDetail` object is neither `null` nor `undefined`.It looks like as shown below at run time.

It defines as shown below.

```
 vm.occupantDetail = {
            contactDetail: {},
     };
```

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I check if an object has a property in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/135448/how-do-i-check-if-an-object-has-a-property-in-javascript)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I test for an empty JavaScript object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/679915/how-do-i-test-for-an-empty-javascript-object)

Comment: will you share your javascript object ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the it using

```
Object.keys(vm.occupantDetail.contactDetail).length
```

Comment: Can you tell me what is `a` ? Or can you show how to do that by using same object which I have used ?

Comment: its the object  you want check for, in your case `vm.occupantDetail.contactDetail`

Answer (score 0):

It appears from your code that your `vm.occupantDetail.contactDetail` object is simply an empty object, and the `__proto__` property that you are seeing is the [protoype](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_object_prototypes.asp) property of the `Object`. If you want to check if an object is `null`, the following conditional will do the job.

```
if (obj == null) { ... }
```

*However*, it appears that you want to check if an object is *empty*, which is different. If you want to check if a specified object has no assigned properties, try the following function.

```
function isEmpty(map) {
   for(var key in map) {
      if (map.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
         return false;
      }
   }
   return true;
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to do `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj).length === 0`?

Comment: @domyos I think that may run into issues if you extend the `Object` via prototype, I'm not 100% sure though.

Answer (score 0):

Check the length of your object also the length of your keys.

```
        if (Object.keys(vm.occupantDetail.contactDetail).length > 0)
        { 
            // vm.occupantDetail.contactDetail has values
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

check it by jQuery.isEmptyObject()

```
jQuery.isEmptyObject({}); // true
jQuery.isEmptyObject({ foo: "bar" });
```

https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.isEmptyObject/