# Which method to use when asking whether object's property is defined in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

Learning JavaScript I ran across two methods to find out whether object has defined property.

```
Method A
if ('propertyName' in object) { }
Method B
if (object.propertyName) { }
```

Using `console.log()` I found out that Method A yields boolean value whereas Method B yields either `undefined` or value of the property if defined.

Are there any other differences between these two methods or reasons I should prefer using one over another? 
If there are no differences I would prefer using Method B since there is no need for using string.

Comment: Do you need to differentiate between *falsey* values like `undefined`, `false`, `null` etc? That's where a plain `if (o.p)` differs significantly.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/135448/how-do-i-check-if-an-object-has-a-property-in-javascript?