# Sort array with undefined object

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, sorting, ecmascript-6

Stuck with one problem. I have to sort my array of objects by some values. For example by department name -> `department.name`. But sometimes `department` will have no any keys `department: undefined`. So when i will use `department.name` i will get errors.

Questions is: Is it possible to sort array with this criteria? And how to modify my function to do it right way?

Thanks!

***My function***

```
sort(type) {
    const isSorted = this.state.sorted[type];
            let direction = isSorted ? 1 : -1;
            const sorted = [].slice.call(employees).sort((a, b) => {
                if (a.department[type] === b.department[type]) { return 0; }
                    return a.department[type] > b.department[type] ? direction : direction * -1;
            }
}
```

Comment: Check whether it's undefined and do something else.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/135448/how-do-i-check-if-an-object-has-a-property-in-javascript