# Check if Object -> key is already in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an `array` looking like this

```
const arr = ["a", "b", "c", {d: [...]}, {e: [...]}, "f", "g"]
```

How would I check if the `object` with the `key` `d` or `e` is in the array?

Comment: Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/135448/how-do-i-check-if-an-object-has-a-property-in-javascript). Then all you need to do is loop through the array and test each member.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `some()` if you only need to check for key on one level.

```js
const arr = ["a", "b", "c", {d: [1]}, {e: [1]}, "f", "g"]

var check = arr.some(function(e) {
  return typeof e == 'object' && (e.hasOwnProperty('d') || e.hasOwnProperty('e'))
})

console.log(check)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ES2015's `Object.keys()` to get object's own enumerable keys:

```
const hasMatchingObject = arr.some((element) => {
    return (
        element instanceof Object &&
        (
            Object.keys(element).includes("d") ||
            Object.keys(element).includes("e")
        )
    );
});
```

(notice that I've used `includes` which is part of ES2016, but you could also use the old `indexOf` method).

Answer (score 0):

You could use [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) with [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):

```
const arr = ["a", "b", "c", {d: [{id:1, value:'value d'}]}, 
                {e: [{id:1, value:'value e'}]}, "f", "g"];  

console.log(arr.find(i => i.d)); // will return the object/array
console.log(arr.find(i => i.x)); // undefined, it doesn't exist
```