# How to get a nested array value from a redux state

Tags: javascript, redux

This function returns the redux state

```
this.context.store.getState()
```

Here's the state

```
Map {size: 2, _root: ArrayMapNode, __ownerID: undefined, __hash: undefined, __altered: false}
```

If I do this.context.store.getState()["size"] it will return 2, which is perfect. Now I want to retrieve place_id from the following. How do I do it?

```
{_root:
  entries:
    [place_id: 'TRYING TO GET THIS VALUE"
```

But if I do getState()["_root"]["entries"]["place_id"] it doesn't work (because it's within an array?)

Answer (score 2):

`entries` is an array, meaning it may contain multiple objects. You need to select the object by index. So for example, if you were to get the ID of the first place, your code would look like this:

```
getState()._root.entries[0].place_id
```

Or

```
getState()["_root"]["entries"][0]["place_id"]
```

Be aware that if you try to access a property of an object that doesn't exist, your code will break. So you need to check if the property exist before accessing it - [How do I check if an object has a property in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/135448/how-do-i-check-if-an-object-has-a-property-in-javascript)

Comment: It will work for `{_root:entries:[ {place_id: 'TRYING TO GET THIS VALUE"`. OP has different result.

Comment: This is better than using the index of the array. Thank you :) And thanks for the answer Hugo.