# Error while accessing javascript array element inspite of having checks

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I am doing following in my javascript code

```
if(
  typeof player['stats'] != undefined &&
  typeof player['stats']['guild'] != undefined &&
  typeof player['stats']['guild']['master'] != undefined &&
  typeof player['stats']['guild']['master']['since'] != undefined
)
```

However I get error:

`Cannot read property 'since' of null`

I have been stuck with this for a while. Can any javascript gurus help me please?

Comment: Remove the `typeof`s and `!= undefined` parts.

Comment: Use `lodash#get` to simplify this monstrous construction.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir that did not help :( update: did not see your edit, let me try again

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir - that worked! you should post that as answer, so I can accept it and others can also be benefitted!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I check if an object has a property in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/135448/how-do-i-check-if-an-object-has-a-property-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

typeof returns string, so compare against "undefined"

```
if(
  typeof player['stats'] != "undefined" &&
  typeof player['stats']['guild'] != "undefined" &&
  typeof player['stats']['guild']['master'] != "undefined" &&
  player['stats']['guild']['master'] != null &&
  typeof player['stats']['guild']['master']['since'] != "undefined"
)
```

Comment: That still won't solve the problem as `player['stats']['guild']['master']` is `null` not `undefined` (deduced from the error)..

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir  yes missed that, it will need to compare for null too, code corrected, thanks for pointing

Comment: @UndefinedVariable check now

Answer (score 1):

Just check if the value is truthy:

```
if(
  player['stats'] &&
  player['stats']['guild'] &&
  player['stats']['guild']['master'] &&
  player['stats']['guild']['master']['since'] != undefined    // only check the last one as it is probably not an object but another value such as 0 (depending on what your data looks like, if you have it as an object then just remove the != undefined check)
)
```

Comment: What if `player['stats']['guild']['master']['since']` has _falsy_ value (false , 0 , "" )?

Comment: @alexmac It mostly going to be an object that he is going to use inside the body of `if`. But I've added a check just in case.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a fairly simple object getter function which you pass the object and then a dot-delimited key to find a value like so:

```
function getObj(obj, key) {
  return key.split(".").reduce((acc, cur) => {
    if (acc !== undefined) {
      return acc[cur];
    }
    return acc;
  }, obj);
}
```

Then, you can grab the value that you want and see if it's undefined or not:

```
const player = {
  stats: {
    guild: {
      master: {
        since: '2004'
      }
    }
  }
};

const since = getObj(player, 'stats.guild.master.since');
if (since) {
  // do some code
}
```

This is a handy utility function you can use on any object and makes your if statement much prettier.

Comment: I think this will work only if you remove the ` !== undefined` and add it in the if statement `if (since !== undefined)` because in his case master is `null`

Comment: Updated so it gracefully handles null and undefined: https://jsfiddle.net/vhnoqo8u/

Answer (score 0):

You can also avoid the multiple lookups with a temporary variable:

```js
player = { stats: { guild: { master: null } } }

if ((temp = player.stats) && 
    (temp = temp.guild)   && 
    (temp = temp.master)  && 
    (temp = temp.since) !== undefined)        
    console.log(true , temp)
else
    console.log(false, temp)


player.stats.guild.master = { since: 'today' }

if ((temp = player.stats) && 
    (temp = temp.guild)   && 
    (temp = temp.master)  && 
    (temp = temp.since) !== undefined)        
    console.log(true , temp)
else
    console.log(false, temp)
```