# Javascript object check if property exists

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript object called **file**, I am trying to check if this object has file.xhr.response property contained in it. I have tried like this..

```
if (file.xhr.response) {
    console.log(Exists);
} else {
    console.log(Missing);
}
```

This works when **file.xhr.response** exists but if it doesn't then it throws an error...

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'response' of undefined
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: When it throws `Cannot read property 'response' of undefined` it doesn't mean that `response` doesn't exist but rather then it's parent doesn't exist, in your case `xhr`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [javascript test for existence of nested object key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2631001/javascript-test-for-existence-of-nested-object-key)

Comment: The error says that `response` is not defined but the code you put in the question doesn't use `response` at all. The problem is not in the code you've shared.

Comment: You can check whether an object has a property written in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/135448/how-do-i-check-if-an-object-has-a-property-in-javascript)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check if object property exists using:

```
if (file && file.xhr && file.xhr.response) {
    // your logic...
}
```

Code:

```js
const a = {
  b: {
    d: 'd'
  }
}

const resultC = a && a.b && a.b.c ? 'Exists' : 'Missing';
console.log('a.b.c', resultC);

const resultD = a && a.b && a.b.d ? 'Exists' : 'Missing';
console.log('a.b.d', resultD);
```

But if you are dealing with a complex/bigger object you can recursively search for the property within the object

Code:

```js
const a = {
  b: {
    d: {
      d: {
        e: {
          f1: {
            g: {
              h: 'h',
            }
          },
          f2: {
            g: {
              h: {
                i: 'i',
              },
            },
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },
}

const checkObjectProp = (o, p) => Object
  .keys(o)
  .some(k => k === p || (typeof o[k] === 'object' && checkObjectProp(o[k], p)))

const resultI = checkObjectProp(a, 'i') ? 'Exists' : 'Missing'
console.log(resultI)
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use something like `if(typeof file.xhr!="undefined")`