# Check object has the key and value

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, filter

**Courses object :**

```
data.courses: [{name: 'JAVA', categoryid: '1'},
{name: 'PHP', categoryid: '1'},
{name: 'HR', categoryid: '2'}]
```

**Categories object:**

```
data.categories: [{catname: 'Information technology',categoryid: '1'},
{catname: 'HR',categoryid: '2'},
{catname: 'Sales',categoryid: '3'}]
```

My Expected result:

**finalObjCategoriesobject:**

```
 data.finalObjCategories: [{catname: 'Information technology',categoryid: '1'},
 {catname: 'HR',categoryid: '2'}]
```

//  `{catname: 'Sales',categoryid: '3'}` removed because there is no course present with this category in courses object.

I want to get only those categories records for which categories have the course data how can I do it.?

```
while(grCategory.next())  {
  var categoryName=grCategory.getValue('name');
  var categoryId=grCategory.getUniqueValue();
  //here condition needed(couse cat lenght > 1 push else dontpush)
  //if (data.courses.hasOwnProperty('name');){
      data.categories.push({name: categoryName, id: categoryId});
  //}
}
```

Comment: It's not really clear what your asking here, and it doesn't help with the object literals you have shown are invalid, they all have duplicate keynames.

Comment: your question not clear, from my understanding this could help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/135448/how-do-i-check-if-an-object-has-a-property-in-javascript

Comment: @Keith  I have updated question can you please check once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is really really unclear, but if I understood it you can use `.map` and `.find` to get what you want.

```js
var courses =  [
  {name: 'JAVA',categoryid: '1'},
  {name: 'PHP',categoryid: '1'},
  {name: 'HR',categoryid: '2'}
]
                
var categories = [
  {catname: 'Information technology',categoryid: '1'},
  {catname: 'HR',categoryid: '2'},
  {catname: 'Sales',categoryid: '3'}
]

var result = [];
courses.map(function(course){
  var crs = categories.find(function(cat){return course.categoryid == cat.categoryid})

  if(typeof crs !== "undefined" && result.indexOf(crs) < 0){
    result.push(crs);
  }    
})

console.log(result)
```

[Here is the fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/3tr5z28c/40/)

Comment: you understood little well I want the reverse `result`. only those` categories` should come in` result` which categories have data in `courses` object.

Comment: Could you update your question with the wanted result?