# Check if key is in the object

Tags: javascript, object

```
var stored_names = {
      332438809: "Bereznyak24",
      489485245: "Bereznyak25"
    }
  if ((data.message.from.id in stored_names) && (data.message.text === "/start")) {
    SendMsg(id, first_reply.text);
  }
```

How can I check if my object has key (or has not) that's equal to `data.message.from.id` value that I get later?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I check if an object has a property in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/135448/how-do-i-check-if-an-object-has-a-property-in-javascript)

Comment: `if (332438809 in stored_names)` should works

Comment: `if(stored_names[data.message.from.id])`

Answer (score 1):

**Your answer should work**, as your are using the `in` keyword (`value in stored_names`).

Another way to check if the value is amongst the keys is to use `Object.key()` to enumerate the keys and `Array.includes`.

```
Object.keys(arr).includes(value);
```

See the [doc for Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

Comment: thanks for the reply! 
Why can't I get this thing working?
`if (( Object.keys(stored_names).includes(data.message.from.id) )`

Comment: You should be good with the code you posted in your question. Verify what data.message.from.id gives you though as well as data.message.text