# Why does my include function is not recognized as a function

Tags: javascript, html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>practice</title>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <meta name="description" content="Creating and Maintaining Student Record Object">
        <script>
                var section = [];
                var name = [];
                var gender = [];
                var age = [];
                var favsub = [];
                var studRec = [];
                function saveButton() {
                    studRec[studRec.length] = {
                        section:document.getElementById("section").value,
                        name:document.getElementById("name").value,
                        gender:document.getElementById("gender").value,
                        age:document.getElementById("age").value,
                        favsub1:document.getElementsByClassName("favsub")[0].value,
                        favsub2:document.getElementsByClassName("favsub")[1].value,
                        favsub3:document.getElementsByClassName("favsub")[2].value,
                    }
                    document.getElementById("saveStud").reset();
                    console.log(studRec[studRec.length-1]);
                    }
                function checker() {
                    var name = document.getElementById("name1").value;
                    var section = document.getElementById("section1").value;
                    var count=studRec.length;
                    var check;
                    for(var i=0;i<count;i++)
                    {
                        check = studRec[i].includes(name,section);
                        if( check == true){
                            return studRec[i];
                        }
                        alert("Info does not exist");
                    }
                    }

            </script>
            <form id="saveStud" method="POST">
              <center>
                <p>Section</p>
                <select id="section" autofocus required>
                  <option value="0">select</option>
                        <option value="truth">truth</option>
                        <option value="faith">faith</option>
                        <option value="honesty">honesty</option>
                        <option value="charity">charity</option>
                        <option value="obedience">obedience</option>
                        <option value="chastity">chastity</option>
                        <option value="generosity">generosity</option>
                        <option value="humility">humility</option>          
                </select><br>
                <p>Student Name</p><input id="name" type="text" required><br>
                <p>Gender</p>
                <select id="gender">
                  <option value="M">Male</option>
                  <option value="F">Female</option>
                </select><br>
                <p>Age</p><input id="age" type="number" required><br>
                <p>Favorite Subjects</p><input class="favsub" type="text" required><br>
                <input class="favsub" type="text" required><br>
                <input class="favsub" type="text" required><br>

                <button onclick="saveButton()">save</button>
                <button type="reset" value="reset">reset</button>
              </center>
            </form>
            <br>
            <form id="search" method="POST">
              <center>
                <button type="button" onclick="checker()">search</button>
                <input id="name1" type="text" placeholder="Enter Student Name" required>
                <select id="section1" autofocus required>
                  <option value="0">select</option>
                        <option value="truth">truth</option>
                        <option value="faith">faith</option>
                        <option value="honesty">honesty</option>
                        <option value="charity">charity</option>
                        <option value="obedience">obedience</option>
                        <option value="chastity">chastity</option>
                        <option value="generosity">generosity</option>
                        <option value="humility">humility</option>          
                </select>
                <br>
                <button type="button">delete</button>

              </center>
            </form>
        </body>

    </html>
```

The code is suppose to store the student's information in an array using the function saveButton()then after that we type the student's name and select the section and using the search button, the function checker() is suppose to display the information if the the info inputted is included in the array studRec but the line check = studRec[i].includes(name,section); does not work. please help

Comment: You need to open the body tag first `<body>`

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki — The body element start tag is optional in HTML.

Comment: have you closed the <head>

Comment: @JamieEltringham — The head element end tag is optional in HTML (so yes, implicitly by having a form start tag)

Comment: @Quentin IMO it's a bad practice to wait from the browser to add the tags for you.

Comment: @Quentin i agree it is bad practice to not close your own tags

Comment: The browser won't add "tags". It will generate a DOM (with *elements*) according to the rules of HTML. Whether or not explicitly providing optional tags is best practise is largely a matter of opinion (there are measurable pros and cons in both directions) and very much nothing to do with the problem at hand.

Answer (score 2):

This is the object you are trying to call `includes` on:

> ```
> {
>     section: document.getElementById("section").value,
>     name: document.getElementById("name").value,
>     gender: document.getElementById("gender").value,
>     age: document.getElementById("age").value,
>     favsub1: document.getElementsByClassName("favsub")[0].value,
>     favsub2: document.getElementsByClassName("favsub")[1].value,
>     favsub3: document.getElementsByClassName("favsub")[2].value,
> }
> ```

You haven't put an `includes` property there and objects don't have a native `includes` method. [Arrays have one](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes), but `{}` creates a plain object, not an array.

See [How do I check if an object has a property in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/135448/how-do-i-check-if-an-object-has-a-property-in-javascript) to test if an object has a property of a given name.

Answer (score 1):

You have wrong understanding of how `.includes` works

Demo

```
[1, 3, 4].includes(3) // true
['apple', 'pie'].includes('american') // false
[{ name: 'John' }, { name: 'Obama' }].includes({ name: 'Obama' }) // true
```

Note what includes accepts as argument, its same data type as in array

Your mistake - checking wrong value signature

```
[{
  section:document.getElementById("section").value,
  name:document.getElementById("name").value,
  gender:document.getElementById("gender").value,
  age:document.getElementById("age").value,
  favsub1:document.getElementsByClassName("favsub")[0].value,
  favsub2:document.getElementsByClassName("favsub")[1].value,
  favsub3:document.getElementsByClassName("favsub")[2].value,
}].includes(name, section) // false
```

Must be

```
[{
  section:document.getElementById("section").value,
  name:document.getElementById("name").value,
  gender:document.getElementById("gender").value,
  age:document.getElementById("age").value,
  favsub1:document.getElementsByClassName("favsub")[0].value,
  favsub2:document.getElementsByClassName("favsub")[1].value,
  favsub3:document.getElementsByClassName("favsub")[2].value,
}, {
  section:1,
  name:1,
  gender:1,
  age:1,
  favsub1:1,
  favsub2:1,
  favsub3:1,
}].includes({
  section:1,
  name:1,
  gender:1,
  age:1,
  favsub1:1,
  favsub2:1,
  favsub3:1,
}) // true
```

Answer (score 0):

The function `includes()` is available for arrays. But while `studRec` is an array, the members of `studRec` (`studRec[i]`) are not arrays, but objects.

To search for an object inside the array based on some criteria use the [`find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) function of the array with a callback that checks the criteria.

```
function checker() 
{
    let name = document.getElementById("name1").value;
    let section = document.getElementById("section1").value;

    let result = studRec.find(function(element) {
            return element.name == name && element.section == section;
        }
    );

    if(!result)
    {
        alert("Info does not exist");
    }

    return result;
}
```