# If condition returns false if a number exists, but is 0

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a class with an optional field `startDateHour`:

```
export class Test {
  startDateHour?: number;

  // more fields, constructor etc.
}
```

I want to do something, if `startDateHour` exists:

```
if (test.startDateHour) {
  //do something
}
```

The problem is that this check doesnt work as expected when `startDateHour` is 0. If its 0 it still exists and i want to execute the code, but `if (startDateHour)` returns false in that case.

Of course i could do something like:

```
if (test.startDateHour || test.startDateHour === 0) {
  // do something
}
```

But is there a better way, like one check which does both the things above?

Comment: `test.hasOwnProperty("startDateHour")`, `"startDateHour" in test`, `test.startDateHour == undefined`, `typeof test.startDateHour == "undefined"`. Take your pick.

Comment: at any time 0 is false..

Comment: `if (!isNaN(test.startDateHour))` is also an option

Comment: This is JS basics Falsy, Truthy - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy

Comment: What you could do, is write a utility method, that checks for not `null` and not `undefined` and can be used like: `if(isAssigned(test.startDateHour))`

Comment: @r3dst0rm or avoid the utility method and just do `val == null` or `val == undefined` - in both cases, you're checking for *both* of these. It's a slight "hack" with loose equality but it's probably the best use of it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I check if an object has a specific property in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/135448/how-do-i-check-if-an-object-has-a-specific-property-in-javascript)

Comment: Simple `if(!test1.startDateHour) {}` does the trick as `undefined`, `null` and `0` all equate to `false` and anything else as true.

Answer (score 2):

0 is falsy. But the latest typescript version provides another operator called Nullish Coalescing. Depending on what you want to do within the if you might want to use that.

Read about it here for example: https://dev.to/obinnaogbonnajoseph/optional-chaining-and-nullish-coalescing-typescript-3-7-5899

Comment: Nice information. Allthough, how would it look then: `if (test.startDateHour ?? undefined !== undefined) { /* something */ }` ?

Comment: You wouldn't use the operator within the if-condition. That's why I said depends on what he wants to do within the if statement. `0 ?? 1 returns 0`,  while `0 || 1 returns 1`

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
if(!isNaN(test.startDateHour)) {
}
```

Comment: if(!isNaN(test.startDateHour)){} no ?