# How to Access Javascript object property if only that property is available - ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to access Javascript object property if and if only that property is available.

`object.property.anotherInnerProperty ="value`"

To access and check above value we normally use following way

```
if(object && object.property && object.property.anotherInnerProperty=="value")
   then do this
```

Is there any effective and less code method to access object.property.anotherInnerProperty ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I check if an object has a specific property in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/135448/how-do-i-check-if-an-object-has-a-specific-property-in-javascript)

Comment: Would you mind using `lodash.get` method for this?

Comment: @coding_Lover what you have done is completely okay to do. Even if there is more code it is most safest approach

Answer (score 3):

You can use [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) to make your code less verbose:

```
if(object?.property?.anotherInnerProperty === "value") {
 // then do this
}
```

Note that this is still a new feature of the language, so you might need some transpiling to make it work in most of the browsers.

Comment: ...or even in the newest browsers, judging by the *Browser compatibility* table.

Comment: Indeed, updated the answer.

Comment: @Clarity It could be a very useful feature.

Comment: @AL-zami it's stage 4 of TC39 now and will be a part of ES2020.

Comment: It works Thanks, however there is an error complains by VS code. But still works.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [lodash.get](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash.get) method:

```js
const object = {
  property: {
    innerProperty: 'foo'
  }
};

const anotherObject = null;

console.log(_.get(object, 'property.innerProperty'));
console.log(_.get(anotherObject, 'property.innerProperty'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```